# How to make really wide tables narrower

Tags: tables, width

Is there a way to fix extremely wide tables?

I have the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
            \toprule
                &  Manual Tests & Randoop 2.5 Minutes With GUI Code &  Randoop 2.5 Minutes Without GUI Code &  Randoop 5 Minutes Without GUI Code \\ \midrule
    \% Covered Instructions &  \textbf{82.40\%} &  21.25\% &  21.30\% &  \textbf{22.10\%} \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

And it looks like so:

[image: look]

Is there a way to make the cells slimmer? If relevant I am using `scrreprt`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `p{width}` column type for a fixed column, text will wrap automatically. For example:

```
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{p{3cm}}}
\toprule
  &  Manual Tests & Randoop 2.5 Minutes With GUI Code &  Randoop 2.5 Minutes Without GUI Code &  Randoop 5 Minutes Without GUI Code \\ \midrule
\% Covered Instructions &  \textbf{82.40\%} &  21.25\% &  21.30\% &  \textbf{22.10\%} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

You can also use `\shortstack` and use `\\` for manual line break. For example:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
  &  Manual Tests & \shortstack{Randoop 2.5 Minutes\\ With GUI Code} &  \shortstack{Randoop 2.5 Minutes\\ Without GUI Code} &  \shortstack{Randoop 5 Minutes\\ Without GUI Code} \\ \midrule
\% Covered Instructions &  \textbf{82.40\%} &  21.25\% &  21.30\% &  \textbf{22.10\%} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

`\shortstack` here can be replaced by a small `tabular` envronment, for better vertical alignment:

```
\newcommand{\minitab}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
  &  Manual Tests & \minitab{Randoop 2.5 Minutes\\ With GUI Code} &  \minitab{Randoop 2.5 Minutes\\ Without GUI Code} &  \minitab{Randoop 5 Minutes\\ Without GUI Code} \\ \midrule
\% Covered Instructions &  \textbf{82.40\%} &  21.25\% &  21.30\% &  \textbf{22.10\%} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Furthermore, you can use [`makecell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) for more flexible commands. `\shortstack` or `\minitab` can be replaced by `\makecell`, `\thead` etc.

```
% \usepackage{makecell}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
  &  Manual Tests & \thead{Randoop 2.5 Minutes\\ With GUI Code} &  \thead{Randoop 2.5 Minutes\\ Without GUI Code} &  \thead{Randoop 5 Minutes\\ Without GUI Code} \\ \midrule
\% Covered Instructions &  \textbf{82.40\%} &  21.25\% &  21.30\% &  \textbf{22.10\%} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thank you. That `makecell` package did the trick.

Answer (score 9):

You could break lines in wide cells. For this you could use p cells instead of l, such as p{2cm}.

I recommend

- Using the `tabularx` package to adjust the table to the text width
- Using features of the `array` package to insert commands into the column definition
- Getting better breaks in cells by `ragged2e`
- Loading `microtype` for finer automatic justification
- Using `booktabs` of course, you do it already as I can see.

It's a bit much to tell - just check out the package documentation.

Here's a quick example for your table:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{P{2.5cm}lYYY}
\toprule
    &  Manual Tests & Randoop 2.5 Minutes With GUI Code &  Randoop 2.5 Minutes Without GUI Code &  Randoop 5 Minutes Without GUI Code \\ \midrule
    \% Covered Instructions &  \textbf{82.40\%} &  21.25\% &  21.30\% &  \textbf{22.10\%} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this example, how would you vertically align the Manual Tests Cell?

Comment: @Tiago: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells