# How to get rid of these excessive rules?

Tags: tables, loops

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%cannot be minimal
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen, xspace}
\newcounter{xyz}
\setcounter{xyz}{1}
\def\and{&\xspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*2{c|}}\hline
\whiledo{\value{xyz}<6}%
{\thexyz \and something\stepcounter{xyz} \\\hline}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also removes the last two vertical lines:

```
\newcommand*{\condition}{\value{xyz}<6}
\begin{longtable}{|*2{c|}}\hline
\whiledo{\condition}%
{\thexyz \and something\stepcounter{xyz}%
\ifthenelse{\condition}{\\\hline}{\\\hline\end{longtable}}}
```

It's funny that these lines appear if I take `\\\hline` out of this `\ifthenelse`, similar if I put `\end{longtable}` after that (even with `%` before the line break). And, actually, I don't like ending an environment within a loop construction.

Comment: +1 but the coding workflow is so cryptic. :-) Waiting for another cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

From the `booktabs` package documentation:

> **2 The layout of formal tables**
>
> You will not go far wrong if you remember
>   two simple guidelines at all times:
>
> 1. Never, ever use vertical rules.
> 2. Never use double rules. These guidelines may seem extreme but I have
>      never found a good argument in favour
>      of breaking them. For example, if you
>      feel that the information in the left
>      half of a table is so different from
>      that on the right that it needs to be
>      separated by a vertical line, then you
>      should use two tables instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen, xspace}

\newcounter{xyz}
\def\and{&\xspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{>{\stepcounter{xyz}\thexyz}cc}
\toprule
\whiledo{\value{xyz}<5}
  {\and something \\}
 & \xspace something \\
\bottomrule
 \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the `booktabs`, but it is the same as what doncherry did.

Comment: @xport: in a sense, yes. But with my code I also wanted to show that you can move let the table format specification handle the counter.

Comment: Yes. Of course but I have been using it for years. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells/7227#7227

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}%cannot be minimal
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen, xspace}
\newcounter{xyz}
\setcounter{xyz}{1}
\def\and{&\xspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*2{c|}}\hline
\whiledo{\value{xyz}<5}%
{\thexyz \and something\stepcounter{xyz} \\\hline}%
\thexyz \and something\stepcounter{xyz}\\\hline%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: + 1 but I actually want all row constructions to be in a single looping body.

Comment: @xport: Well, I guess Stefan's answer solves that. If you just wanna make sure any changes you make to the table row get transferred to the last row as well, we could define a `\newcommand{\makerow}{\thexyz \and something\stepcounter{xyz}\\\hline}` that is called in the loop body and once afterwards.