# \cellcolor overwrites table lines

Tags: tables, color, rules

I have a table which I want to fill with multiple colors, each cell possibly different from another. Which means, I can't make use of e.g. `\columncolor` (as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/cellcolor-overwrites-partial-horizontal-lines-cline) post).

While the table without any colors looks just fine (code at the end):
[image: empty table]

...the table with one or more filled cells overwrites the table grid.
[image: filled tables]

**So my question is:** Is there a way to, for example, redraw the grid after filling the cells or something?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}
% Cline redefining to add line thickness
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}
}


\definecolor{intnull}{RGB}{213,229,255}
\definecolor{inteins}{RGB}{128,179,255}
\definecolor{intzwei}{RGB}{42,127,255}
\definecolor{intdrei}{RGB}{0,85,212}
\definecolor{intvier}{RGB}{0,51,128}
\definecolor{intfunf}{RGB}{0,34,85}


\begin{document}
% Empty table
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}p{1.5cm}}!{\vrule width 1.5pt}l}
\centering 4 &
\centering 10 &
\centering 24 &
\centering 48 &
\centering 72 &\\ \Cline{1.5pt}{0-4}
 &  &  &  &  & Optic tectum \\ \Cline{1.5pt}{3-5}
 &  &  &  &  & Retina \\ \Cline{1.5pt}{3-5}
 &  &  &  &  & Myomeres \\ \Cline{1.5pt}{0-4}
 &  &  &  &  & Arches \\ \Cline{1.5pt}{0-4}
\end{tabular} \\

\hspace*{1cm}

% Partically filled table
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}p{1.5cm}}!{\vrule width 1.5pt}l}
\centering 4 &
\centering 10 &
\centering 24 &
\centering 48 &
\centering 72 &\\ \Cline{1.5pt}{0-4}
 & \cellcolor{intnull} &  & \cellcolor{intvier} &  & Optic tectum \\ \Cline{1.5pt}{3-5}
 & \cellcolor{intnull} &  & \cellcolor{intnull} &  & Retina \\ \Cline{1.5pt}{3-5}
 & \cellcolor{intnull} &  & \cellcolor{intdrei} &  & Myomeres \\ \Cline{1.5pt}{0-4}
 & \cellcolor{inteins} &  & \cellcolor{inteins} &  & Arches \\ \Cline{1.5pt}{0-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please don't just post fragments of code that can not be run, always post complete small documents.

The fix should be exactly as in the other question. As documented `colortbl` is incompatible with `\cline`, you need to use `\hhline` instead. The fact that the cell backgrounds are different colours is irrelevant to the problem of `\cline` including negative spacing so that it comes under the colour.

Comment: This leads to new, but different problems: I read your documentation of the hhline package and used `\hhline{*{2}{|~}*{3}{|-}|~|}` instead of `\Cline`. Now I have white lines where no line should be. Using actual multirows has no different effect.

Comment: It might be better to solve this in a [follow-up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/hhline-adds-white-line-where-no-line-is-intended)

Answer (score 4):

Just put the command `\cellcolor[]{}` inside brackets {} and it will not overwrite the table lines like this

```
\hline

{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}} Chapter & Title \\

\hline
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they will be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: If you just use \hline and not \cline that is working perfect and is much easier implemented! I can not tick it as right answer as this is already done with the first answer.

Comment: no, it doesn't help. I just tested it and the result is the same, I have still problems with those lines