# \hhline adds white line where no line is intended

Tags: tables, color, rules

In a table, containing colored cells, i want to have a `\hline` dividing only some cells, similar to `\cline` but compatible with coloring single cells with `\cellcolor`, which is possible by using `\hhline` with fitting parameters.

Now I have come to the appended code, which results in:
[image: tables_hhline]

There are two points I want to work around.

First, the black cells should not be crossed by a white line. Since they will not be black in the final document, I need them to be not black, either. Is there a way to not draw any line at all? These cells should look like a multirow cell, colored consistently.

The second problem are the hline fragments at the right end of the table. How can I get rid of them?

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}


\begin{document}
% Empty table
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}p{1.5cm}}!{\vrule width 1.5pt}l}
\centering 4 &
\centering 10 &
\centering 24 &
\centering 48 &
\centering 72 &\\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~|}
 &  &  &  &  & Optic tectum \\ \hhline{*{2}{|~}*{3}{|-}|~|}
 &  &  &  &  & Retina \\ \hhline{*{2}{|~}*{3}{|-}|~|}
 &  &  &  &  & Myomeres \\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~|}
 &  &  &  &  & Arches \\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~|}
\end{tabular} \\

\hspace*{1cm}

% Partically filled table
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}p{1.5cm}}!{\vrule width 1.5pt}l}
\centering 4 &
\centering 10 &
\centering 24 &
\centering 48 &
\centering 72 &\\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~|}
 & \cellcolor{black} &  & \cellcolor{green} &  & Optic tectum \\ \hhline{*{2}{|~}*{3}{|-}|~|}
 & \cellcolor{black} &  & \cellcolor{red} &  & Retina \\ \hhline{*{2}{|~}*{3}{|-}|~|}
 & \cellcolor{black} &  & \cellcolor{blue} &  & Myomeres \\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~|}
 & \cellcolor{blue} &  & \cellcolor{yellow} &  & Arches \\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are specifying a final hhline fragment

```
\hhline{*{2}{|~}*{3}{|-}|~|}
```

You need

```
 \hhline{*{2}{|~}*{3}{|-}|~}
```

The "white line" is not a rule drawn over the black background it is just a lack of background, thus you need to fill it, the easiest way, as shown in the previous question is not to use `~` in the `\hhline` (which does exactly what you ask and does not draw any line at all) but instead use `-` but colour the rule using `>{...}` to match the cell colour.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I'm glad you people are not only competent but also quick and friendly.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more on how to apply colour to `\hhline`. I don't quite understand `>{}`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @71GA There are lots of examples in the hhline documentation,  `texdoc hhline` then search for Richard

Comment: I found this document http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/hhline.pdf but there is no description on how to use color. There is allso no Richard string inside. I don't think I understand your reply.

Comment: @71GA sorry the coloured hhline examples are in colortbl (by the way you should have hhline documentation on your local system, not only on ctan) but anyway page 6 of http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/colortbl/colortbl.pdf

Comment: How can I control hhline thickness?

Comment: @Silva best not to ask new questions as comments on ancient answers but `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1cm}` (before the tabular) will give thicker rules or (better) use `booktabs` package.

Comment: @Charlise, sorry, but I need a number of horizontal lines in the same table, each line has its thickness, does the hhline have an argument for thickness, or is there a seperate command that can be repeated within the same table?

Comment: @Silva comments should not be used like this. use booktabs which gives you thick \toprule thinner \midrule and other possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

1. If the look of black cells should be `\multirow`-esque, then colouring the lines black would do it. For this, I used a `-` instead of `~` to draw the horizontal rules for the second column;
2. Using `|` indicates a "vline which 'cuts' through a double (or single) hline" (according to the [`hhline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) documentation). Removing this from your `\hhline` specification at the end drops the "hline fragments."
3. Since you're using `\vline 1.5pt` as your column divisions, you might as well use

   ```
   \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
   ```

   to have a consistent look for your table. Otherwise you will notice little indents in your vertical rules.

Here's a MWE showcasing the above:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{color}% http://ctan.org/pkg/color
%\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{colortbl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

\begin{document}
% Empty table
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}%
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}p{1.5cm}}!{\vrule width 1.5pt}l}
\centering 4 &
\centering 10 &
\centering 24 &
\centering 48 &
\centering 72 &\\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~|}
 &  &  &  &  & Optic tectum \\ \hhline{*{2}{|~}*{3}{|-}|~|}
 &  &  &  &  & Retina \\ \hhline{*{2}{|~}*{3}{|-}|~|}
 &  &  &  &  & Myomeres \\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~|}
 &  &  &  &  & Arches \\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~|}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% Partically filled table
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}%
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{|p{1.5cm}}|l}
\centering 4 &
\centering 10 &
\centering 24 &
\centering 48 &
\centering 72 &\\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~}
 & \cellcolor{black} &  & \cellcolor{green} &  & Optic tectum \\ \hhline{|~*{4}{|-}|~}
 & \cellcolor{black} &  & \cellcolor{red} &  & Retina \\ \hhline{|~*{4}{|-}|~}
 & \cellcolor{black} &  & \cellcolor{blue} &  & Myomeres \\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~}
 & \cellcolor{blue} &  & \cellcolor{yellow} &  & Arches \\ \hhline{*{5}{|-}|~}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @1. - I chose the color black only to contrast the white line. The cells will not be black in the final document, as I said, but thanks for the effort =)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The rules specified the command `\Hline` (of `nicematrix`) are not drawn in the blocks (constructed by the command `\Block`).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{5}{p{1.5cm}}}[colortbl-like,last-col,vlines,rules/width=1.5pt]
\centering 4 &
\centering 10 &
\centering 24 &
\centering 48 &
\centering 72 &\\ 
\Hline
\Block{*-1}{} 
 & \Block[fill=red!15]{3-1}{} 
    &  & \cellcolor{green} &  & Optic tectum \\ 
\Hline
 &  &  & \cellcolor{red} &  & Retina \\ 
\Hline
 &  &  & \cellcolor{blue} &  & Myomeres \\ 
\Hline
 & \cellcolor{blue} 
    &  & \cellcolor{yellow} &  & Arches \\ 
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]