# How to control table page breaking using \longtabu, \multirow, colortbl and \hhline

Tags: tables, longtable, colortbl, cline, hhline

I have a probably quite specific LaTeX problem using tables, due to the needed specification of the table, which are (mainly):

- I need support for multiple pages
- I need a lot of multicolumns
- I need colored cells
- **I need the possibility to control page breaks in the table** (This means, I have blocks of rows that have to stay together [see MWE])
- I need partial table rules and want to see them ;-)

I used a specific cline version first (included in the MWE), which adds the page breaking control, but \cline is not compatible with colortbl ( [Cellcolor overwrites partial horizontal lines (\cline)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/cellcolor-overwrites-partial-horizontal-lines-cline) ). So I changed to \hhline, but now I have lost page break control, which is important.

So my main question is: 
**Is it possible to use \hhline and have control of the page breaks at the same time?**

I know it probably has to do with a penality, but I don't know how I may add it, or if it is even possible.

*P.S.: I know that \hhline produces unwanted white lines, but there is a way to fix it ( [\hhline adds white line where no line is intended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/hhline-adds-white-line-where-no-line-is-intended) ). I just left it out of the MWE to keep it smaller.*

---

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a7paper,oneside]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{longtable,tabu}     
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} 
\usepackage{hhline}


% No-break cline version
\makeatletter
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
\omit
\@multicnt#1%
\advance\@multispan\m@ne
\ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
\@multicnt#2%
\advance\@multicnt-#1%
\advance\@multispan\@ne
\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
\cr
\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother

% Shortcut
\newcommand{\cc}[1]{\cellcolor{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X|X|X|}

\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\cc{yellow}Main Entry} \\* 
\hhline{|~|-|-|}

% No break control :(
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \hhline{|~|-|-|}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \hhline{|~|-|-|}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \hhline{|~|-|-|}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \hhline{|~|-|-|}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\ \hline


\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\cc{yellow}Main Entry} \\* 
\cline{2-3}

% Break control, but no rules :(
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \cline{2-3}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \cline{2-3}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \cline{2-3}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \cline{2-3}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\ \hline


\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\cc{yellow}Main Entry} \\* 
\cline{2-3}

{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \cline{2-3}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \cline{2-3}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \cline{2-3}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\* \cline{2-3}
{\cc{yellow}} & {\cc{red}Sub} & {\cc{red}Val} \\ \hline

& & \kill % Needed for correct table calculation

\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Page one of the table:
[image: Page one of the table]

Both pages - with cline, I can control the page breaks:
[image: Both pages - with cline, I can control the page breaks]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: \pagebreak[3] is supposed to encourage a break at that location, but it rarely has any effect.  The needspace package does a better job, if you know how much space you need.