# How create this table

Tags: tables

I want create this table

[image]

I have this code:

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis}  
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{copyrightbox}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
      \centering
        \copyrightbox[b]{
          \begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            technique & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{aaaaa}\\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{=}{$\nu$SVM} & Margen C &  Gamma\\
            \cline{2-3}
             & 1e-1 & 1e-2  \\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{=}{OC-SVM} & Margen C & Gamma\\
            \cline{2-3}
             & 1e-1 & 1e-2  \\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{=}{RNA} & Lr & error\\
            \cline{2-3}
             & 0.9 & 0.0001  \\
            \hline
    % etc. ...
          \end{tabular}   
        }{copyright info text}
    \end{table} 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: The `ociamthesis` class is not available under MikTeX

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear: 1) where does your used class comes from? Please add a link to it! 2) What exactly do you want to get? You only presented an screenshot of a table without content, but your code has content. Please explain your problem better! Do you not know how to get 4 columns? Do you not know to get the empty space in lines?

Comment: Why do you use multirows? Those are not in your example image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first starting point is to start with `colortbl` and `hhline` packages and then modify the rule and cell colors one by one. I modified your `documentclass` to `article`. I have no idea what your class means (Sorry!).

Of course, an example to start with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/hhline-adds-white-line-where-no-line-is-intended
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
      \centering
        \copyrightbox[b]{
          \begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
            technique & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{aaaaa}\\
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
             {\cellcolor{cyan}}& {\cellcolor{cyan}Margen C} &  {\cellcolor{cyan}Gamma}\\
             %I dont yet know how to do it locally, so modiying the multirow color globally and then redefining it.
            \hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{cyan}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|}
             \multirow{-2}{=}{{\cellcolor{cyan}$\nu$SVM}}& {\cellcolor{cyan}1e-1} & {\cellcolor{cyan}1e-2}  \\
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
            \multirow{2}{=}{OC-SVM} & Margen C & Gamma\\
            %\hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
             & 1e-1 & 1e-2  \\
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
            \multirow{2}{=}{RNA} & Lr & error\\
            %\hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
             & 0.9 & 0.0001  \\
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
    % etc. ...
          \end{tabular}   
        }{copyright info text}
    \end{table} 
    \end{document}
```

this would yield you with

[image]

PS: I did not fully edit your table, that is something you can DIY.

Comment: i sorry 
I could not answer, I fell asleep, just edit my question