# Multirow texts overlapping with hline in this table

Tags: tables

the edges are not drawn, why ? 
How can it be solved?

[image]

I want complete table:

[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/hhline-adds-white-line-where-no-line-is-intended
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
      \centering
        \copyrightbox[b]{
          \begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|c|}
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
            technique & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{aaaaa}\\
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}

             %I dont yet know how to do it locally, so modiying the multirow color globally and then redefining it.
            \hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{cyan}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|}
             \multirow{-2}{=}{{\cellcolor{cyan}1}}& {\cellcolor{cyan}1e-1} & {\cellcolor{cyan}1e-2}  & {\cellcolor{cyan}1e-2}  \\
             \multirow{-2}{=}{{2}}& {1e-1} & {1e-2}  & {1e-2}  \\
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
            \multirow{-2}{=}{{3}}& {1e-1} & {1e-2}  & {1e-2}  \\
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
            \multirow{-2}{=}{{4}}& {1e-1} & {1e-2}  & {1e-2}  \\
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}
            \multirow{-2}{=}{{5}}& {1e-1} & {1e-2}  & {1e-2}  \\
            \hhline{*{3}{|-}|~|}

    % etc. ...
          \end{tabular}   
        }{copyright info text}
    \end{table} 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Check the number of columns and its alignment in your table definition. Which is conflicting with the `\hhline` formulations.

Comment: @Raaja i new in latex please i need the help

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I'm a bit lost here...

Comment: Do you want those numbers to be placed on those lines?

Comment: @Skillmon 
I put a new image, that image shows what I want to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly what you want.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  technique & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{aaaaa} \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Easiest way to enlarge a table vertically is to redefine `\arraystretch` to something bigger than 1 (`\begingroup` and `\endgroup` added to keep the change local):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\begin{tabular}[]{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  technique & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{aaaaa} \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{cyan}
  1 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  2 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  3 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  4 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
  5 & 1e-1 & 1e-2 & 1e-2 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: How put more spacing in each cell?

Comment: @x-rw horizontally or vertically?

Comment: mmm vertically please

Comment: @x-rw see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/hhline-adds-white-line-where-no-line-is-intended
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \copyrightbox[b]{
            \begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                technique & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{aaaaa}\\
                \hline
                {\cellcolor{cyan}x}& {\cellcolor{cyan}Margen C} &  {\cellcolor{cyan}Gamma}&{\cellcolor{cyan}y}\\
                \hline
                OC-SVM & Margen C & Gamma&1\\\hline
                OC-SVM& 1e-1 & 1e-2 &2 \\
                \hline
                RNA & Lr & error&3\\\hline
                OC-SVM& 0.9 & 0.0001&3  \\
                \hline
                % etc. ...
            \end{tabular}   
        }{copyright info text}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

This would give you:

[image]

Everybody starts as a beginner, it's always better to read the manual first (most of the answers are there per se). Something that I learnt recently ;)