# Using `\hhline` coloring cells of a table

Tags: tables, color

Sorry for this simple question.
I am trying to color some cells of my table. Unfortunately, if I color two neighbouring cells, the lines of the table disappear. I have found some questions about this ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/cellcolor-overwrites-table-lines) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121476/table-cell-color-overlaps-cell-border)) They offer using `\hhline`, but I don't know how I am supposed to use it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Type} \\
\hline
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
    \hline
    X & 53,2\%  &  \cellcolor[gray]{.9}51,6\%  &  \cellcolor[gray]{.9}49\% & 49\% \\ 
    Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  & 49\% & 49\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You mean vertical lines? Don't use them. But they don't disappear. It is only a pdf viewer issue.

Comment: Are you suggesting to leave the code as it is? Do the lines appear on the printed versions then?

Comment: If you are talking about vertical lines, yes, they should appear in print. I see them in sumatrapdf.

Comment: As such your code gives me this in sumatrapdf:   http://i.stack.imgur.com/SyMao.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a viewer issue.