# How to color only one cell in a multicolumn table?

Tags: tables, colortbl

I have the following table in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Time}

\begin{table}[]
{\tiny
\centering
\begin{tabular}{||l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{18}{|l|}{Progress} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{9}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Ta}} & \multicolumn{9}{l|}{Ses} \\ \cline{10-18} 
\multicolumn{9}{|l|}{}& H & B & A & H & B & A & H & B & A \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 14\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{884} &   &   & \cellcolor{black!15}  &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{2-18} 
& \multicolumn{8}{l|}{L} &   &   & \cellcolor{black!15} &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 15\end{tabular}}  & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{666} &   &   &   & \cellcolor{black!55}  &   &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{2-18} 
& \multicolumn{8}{l|}{650} &   &   &   & \cellcolor{black!55}  &   &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{2-18} 
& \multicolumn{8}{l|}{0X} &   &   &   & \cellcolor{black!55}  &   &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{2-18} 
& \multicolumn{8}{l|}{11} &   &   &   & \cellcolor{black!55}  &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you can see below, it produces a table but not what I want. I want to color the cells and still show the horizontal line between them. When I color two consecutive cells, they will look like a single cell.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I added the preamble and the zoomed pdf according to the comments.

Comment: Could you see what happens when you zoom in? Do the lines appear?

Comment: why do many columns `\multicolumn{8}{l|}{884}` is that really spanning 8 columns? it looks like just one.

Comment: It would help if you could post a code that is compilable, complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.  Which package provides `\cellcolor`?

Comment: @jarauh Thanks. I edited the code accordingly. David Carlisle In fact I don't know why there is 8, I just use http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ to generate the table since I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Werner It still no line even if I zoom the pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is to do with the `cline` command, which is detailed in Section 10 of the [`colortbl`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/colortbl) documentation:

> If using this package you would probably better using the
>   - rule type in a \hhline argument, rather than \cline.

So, following this guidance, we can load the [`hhline`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hhline) package and replace

`\cline{2-18}`

with

`\hhline{*{1}{||~}*{17}{|-}}`

The output is:

[image: screenshot]

For reference, you might also see [\cellcolor overwrites table lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/cellcolor-overwrites-table-lines) and [Cellcolor overwrites partial horizontal lines (\cline)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/cellcolor-overwrites-partial-horizontal-lines-cline)

Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Time}

    \begin{table}[]
        {\tiny
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{||*{18}{l|}}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{18}{|l|}{Progress} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{9}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Ta}} & \multicolumn{9}{l|}{Ses} \\ \cline{10-18}
                \multicolumn{9}{|l|}{}& H & B & A & H & B & A & H & B & A \\ \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 14\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{884} &   &   & \cellcolor{black!15} &                      &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hhline{*{1}{||~}*{17}{|-}}%\cline{2-18}
                                                                             & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{L}   &   &   & \cellcolor{black!15} &                      &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
                \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 15\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{666} &   &   &                      & \cellcolor{black!55} &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hhline{*{1}{||~}*{17}{|-}}%\cline{2-18}
                                                                             & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{650} &   &   &                      & \cellcolor{black!55} &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hhline{*{1}{||~}*{17}{|-}}%\cline{2-18}
                                                                             & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{0X}  &   &   &                      & \cellcolor{black!55} &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hhline{*{1}{||~}*{17}{|-}}%\cline{2-18}
                                                                             & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{11}  &   &   &                      & \cellcolor{black!55} &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily draw that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Time}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{NiceTabular}{ll*{9}{c}}[hvlines,color-inside]
\Block[l]{1-*}{Progress} \\
\Block[l]{2-2}{Ta} & & \Block[l]{1-*}{Ses} \\
                   & & H & B & A & H & B & A & H & B & A \\
\Block{2-1}{14} & 884 & & & \cellcolor{gray!15} \\
                & L   & & & \cellcolor{gray!15} \\
\Block{*-1}{15} & 666 & & & & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
                & 650 & & & & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
                & OX  & & & & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
                & 11  & & & & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
% now, for the double vertical rule
\CodeAfter \tikz \draw ([xshift=2pt]4-|1) -- ([xshift=2pt]10-|1) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]