# How to custom table border?

Tags: tables, formatting, border

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-6}
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Group}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Mean}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Median}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Std Desv}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Variance}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & A & 12,012 & 23 & 7,61 & 86,771 \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Efficiency}}} & B & 21,37 & 34 & 76,62 & 26,016 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & A & 0,122 & 0,011 & 0,021 & 0,065 \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Effort}}} & B & 0,216 & 0,332 & 0,177 & 0,024 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Why is not table top border appearing?

[image]

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278327/117050)

Comment: ... or [Cellcolor overwrites partial horizontal lines (\cline)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65231/124842) .