# \cellcolor overwrites table lines (\hhline)

Tags: tables, multirow, cellcolor, hhline

After following the questions related to the same topic where the problem was [using \cline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/cellcolor-overwrites-partial-horizontal-lines-cline), I used the suggestions based on [another related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/cellcolor-overwrites-table-lines). However, I am still facing the same problem where the horizontal lines are covered by the color of the cell. The confusing part is that it is not consistent. It worked for some lines but not the others.

[image: Sample table]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption}   % Unifies the distance between caption and float
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max} %Defines a new operation argmax with no space
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{bm} % For bold math notations use \bm{$..$}
\usepackage{arydshln} % For dashed lines. \hdashline and \cdashline commands which are the dashed counterparts of \hline and \cline

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\inchsign}{^{\prime\prime}}

\usepackage{bm} % For bold math notations use \bm{$..$}



\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htpb]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\thempfootnote}
\center{\caption{\label{tab:classification} Classification.}
\scalebox{1}
{{
\begin{tabular}{m{3cm} m{1cm} m{0.75cm} m{0.25cm} m{2.7cm} m{1.45cm} m{1.45cm} m{1.45cm} m{1.45cm} m{1.45cm}}
\hhline{*{10}{|-}|}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Proposed Classification}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{UShort}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Short}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Medium}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Long}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{ULong}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \hhline{*{10}{|-}|}

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{12}{*}{Indoor}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{7}{*}{Point}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{LOS}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{F}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{I / PC / LOS / F}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.45cm}{}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{12}{*}{$(I)$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{7}{*}{Coverage}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} \\

\hhline{*{3}{|~}*{7}{|-}|}


\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{7}{*}{$(PC)$}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{M}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{I / PC / LOS / M}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.45cm}{}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}}   \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} \\

\hhline{*{2}{|~}*{8}{|-}|}

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{NLOS}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{F}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{I / PC / NLOS / F}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.45cm}{}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}}  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} \\


\hhline{*{3}{|~}*{7}{|-}|}

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{M}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{I / PC / NLOS / M}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.45cm}{NPA}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} \\

\hhline{*{1}{|~}*{9}{|-}|}

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Cellular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{LOS}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{I / CC / LOS}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.45cm}{}}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Coverage}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}}   \\ \hhline{*{2}{|~}*{8}{|-}}


\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$(CC)$} } & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{NLOS}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{I / CC / NLOS}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.45cm}{}}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}}   \\

\hhline{*{10}{|-}|}
\end{tabular}
}}}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Another problem I am facing is that when I place the table in the body of the paper, it creates a problem where vertical lines are displaced. When I isolated the code for the table to create the MWE the problem disappeared.

[image]

Comment: These artifacts are a common viewer issue, try to open the same PDF file with different viewers and you'll see the lines appear in some viewers and disappear in others. For the second problem, this is certainly due to some setting in the used template. Please edit the question adding your real setup and the documentclass you use for people here to help.

Comment: @AboAmmar Thank you! I zoomed in and it actually showed the lines. For the second problem, I edited the code and added the complete list of packages and now the problem appears in the MWE.

Comment: The table is created by totally absurd code. Why do you declare the common column in the table by `m` specifier when this is never used? Each cell begins by `\multicolumn`, which means `\omit` at TeX primitive level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the misplaced vertical lines is a conflict between the `arydshln` and the `hhline` packages. You need to get rid of `arydshln` if you can go without it. If you can't remove `arydshln`, then you may try `tabu`, it's a powerful all-in-one tables package which can work with `hhline` and has its own dash-line styles.

So, in your preamble, you can use `\usepackage{hhline,tabu}`, and to get dashed lines, just define your own style like:

```
\newtabulinestyle{ mydashed=.5pt on 1.5pt off 1.5pt }
```

and use it as normal column specifiers like `c`, `l`, and `r`.

Comment: If anyone bumps into this answer, Tabu is discontinued and `\cellcolor` does not work with it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

off-topic but can be helpful :-): your table is unnecessary complicated ...

- basic problem is solved by [AboAmmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/59109/aboammar) answer, however i suggest you don't use dashed lines in tables at all
- in preamble you have some packages loaded twice and also three-times
- `xcolor` supersede `color`. it is sufficient to load only `xcolor`
- package `subfigure` is obsolete. rather use `subfig` or `subcaption`
- there is no reason to declare all columns as `m` type. it is sufficient to define their width only for the first three columns, others is better to be `c` type. also there is no seem s to be special reason to use `m{...}` type. i would rather use `p{...}`
- all `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` are superfluous
- use of `multirow are wrong, it is suficient to wrote their contents ones and overlaps them for each line of contents
- exploit new options of recent version of the `multirow` package: `{=}`
- instead `\center{... tcaption + table ...}` is suficient to use only `\centering
- use `multirow` only when you cell had to span more table rows. it is not intended for make more vertical space around cells' contents. for this change `arraystretch` (see *mwe* below)
- for coloring of cells in last two columns is more efficient to color complete columns and use `\colorcell` only for exceptions in the first row
- don't use `scalebox` ... it is desperate measure of last resort to fit table in column width

after considering above comments your table becomes:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}% DVIPS OPTION IS SUPERFLUOUS
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
%\usepackage{subfigure} % ABSOLETE
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{arydshln}  % TROUBLEMAKER
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption}   % Unifies the distance between caption and float
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max} %Defines a new operation argmax with no space
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{xcolor}% <-- SECOND TIME
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{bm} % For bold math notations use \bm{$..$}
%\usepackage{arydshln} % For dashed lines. \hdashline and \cdashline commands which are the dashed counterparts of \hline and \cline
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% <-- THIRD TIME
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{bm} % SECOND TIME
\newcommand{\inchsign}{^{\prime\prime}}

% just for test
\usepackage[floats, tightpage, active]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{3mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[htpb]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% FOR FOOTNOTES BELOW TABLE?
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\thempfootnote}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \caption{\label{tab:classification} Classification.}
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{p{1.2cm}|}
                 *{5}{c|}
                 *{2}{>{\columncolor{blue!25}}c|}
                }
\hhline{*{10}{|-}|}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Proposed Classification}
    & UShort    & Short & Medium    & \cellcolor{white}{Long}
                                        & \cellcolor{white}{ULong}  \\
\hhline{*{10}{|-}|}
\multirow{6}{=}{Indoor (I)}
    & \multirow{4}{=}[-1ex]{Point Coverage (PC)}
        & \multirow{2}{=}{LOS}
            & F & I / PC / LOS / F  &       &   &   &   &   \\
\hhline{*{3}{|~}*{7}{|-}|}
    &   &   & M & I / PC / LOS / M  &       &   &   &   &   \\
\hhline{*{2}{|~}*{8}{|-}|}
    &   & \multirow{2}{=}{NLOS}
            & F & I / PC / NLOS / F &       &   &   &   &   \\
\hhline{*{3}{|~}*{7}{|-}|}
    &   &   & M & I / PC / NLOS / M & NPA   &   &   &   &   \\
\hhline{*{1}{|~}*{9}{|-}|}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{Cellular Coverage (CC)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LOS}  & I / CC / LOS  &       &   &   &   &   \\
\hhline{*{2}{|~}*{8}{|-}}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{NLOS}  & I / CC / NLOS &       &   &   &   &   \\
\hhline{*{10}{|-}|}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htpb]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\caption{\label{tab:classification} Classification.}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{3}{p{1.2cm}}*{7}{c}}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
\rectanglecolor{blue!25}{2-9}{7-10}
\Body
  \Block{1-5}{Proposed Classification} & & & & 
      & UShort & Short & Medium & Long & ULong \\
  \Block{6-1}{Indoor (I)}
      & \Block{4-1}{Point\\ Coverage\\ (PC)}
          & \Block{2-1}{LOS}  
              & F & I / PC / LOS / F  \\
      &   &   & M & I / PC / LOS / M  \\
      &   & \Block{2-1}{NLOS} 
              & F & I / PC / NLOS / F \\
      &   &   & M & I / PC / NLOS / M & NPA  \\
      &   \Block{2-1}{Cellular\\ Coverage\\ (CC)}
          & \Block{1-2}{LOS}  & & I / CC / LOS  \\
      &   & \Block{1-2}{NLOS} & & I / CC / NLOS \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

- You need several compilations.
- In `{NiceTabular}`, you have a command `\Block` to merge cells horizontally and vertically.
- You have a key `hvlines` to draw all the rules excepted in the blocks.
- You have commands to color cells, columns and rows. With these tools, you won't have artefacts in some PDF viewers as you have with the tools of `colortbl`.
- You don't need to complete the rows with the ampersands (`&`) if the last cells of your rows are empty.

[image: Output of the above code]