# Remove horizontal rule in multicolumn table with colored background

Tags: rules, colortbl

I try to remove a horizontal rule in multirow / cellcolor setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline,array,multirow,xcolor,colortbl}
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt

\begin{tabular}{@{}|p{1cm}|l@{}}
\cellcolor{lightgray}     &    \cellcolor{lightgray} b \\
\cline{2-2}
\multirow{-2}{\linewidth}{\cellcolor{lightgray} a }&  \cellcolor{lightgray} d
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{@{}|p{1cm}|l}
  \cellcolor{lightgray}     &    \cellcolor{lightgray} b \\
  \hhline{~-}
  \multirow{-2}{\linewidth}{\cellcolor{lightgray} a }&  \cellcolor{lightgray} d
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|l}
  \cellcolor{lightgray}     &    \cellcolor{lightgray} b \\
  \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-}
  \multirow{-2}{\linewidth}{\cellcolor{lightgray} a }&  \cellcolor{lightgray} d
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is what I have got so far. The third attempt looks better, but still not good. Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Yes, the third way is better. You'll improve with this code for the rule: `\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|}`. The very thin line  inside the cell is mainly due to the pdfviewer.

Comment: Use the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) instead.

Comment: @Sveinung For the next project I try out cals instead. Looks much more the way that I want to typeset tables. Thank you!

Comment: @Bernard Thank you! If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I just upvote your comment :-)

Comment: You may also use TikZ to create a overlay, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490721/9632)

Comment: Thank you for you appreciation!. I don't think it should be posted as an answer, as I'm sure it' duplicate – unless I find a better way.

Comment: You may have a look at the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493743/9632).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is  a workaround to remove completely the very thin lines in the multirow cell. I also loaded `xcolor` with option `[table]`, which saves having to load `colortbl`, and I slightly simplified the code with  `>{\columncolor{lightgray}}` in the  tabular preamble. Last remark; when you use `cellcolor{some colour}`, write immediately after the cell contents *without any space*, as this space would be added to the contents and enlarge the cell.

Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline, array, multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\parindent0pt

\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{1cm}|>{\columncolor{lightgray}}l}
  \cellcolor{lightgray} &\cellcolor{lightgray}b \\
  \hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-}
  \multirow{-2}{\linewidth}{\cellcolor{lightgray} a }&\cellcolor{lightgray} d
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{1cm}|>{\columncolor{lightgray}}l}
    & b \\
\noalign{\vskip-0.1pt}
  \hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-}
\noalign{\vskip-0.1pt}
  \multirow{-2}{\linewidth}{ a }&\cellcolor{lightgray}d
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clever solution, however, the code for a complicated table is complex.

Comment: You're right, however one may define a  custom `\myhhline` which incorporates the parameters that won't change between tables with the same problem.