How to draw a partial line on a table excluding a cell
I tried to create a table using the \cline command to exclude a cell containing a multirow, but the line is too thin and when I download the PDF it is not visible at all. What can I do?
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.8cm} | p{1.2cm} p{1.2cm} p{1.2cm} | p{1.2cm} p{1.2cm} p{1cm}}
     \hline
     \rule[-1mm]{0mm}{0.5cm}
     \rowcolor{lightgray}
       & \multicolumn{3}{c |}{\textbf{Fase vapore all'equilibrio}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Fase liquida all'equilibrio}} \\ 
       \cline{2-7}
         \rowcolor{lightgray}
         \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Miscela}}& $y_{n-esano}$ & $y_{benzene}$ & $y_{toluene}$ & $x_{n-esano}$ & $x_{benzene}$ & $x_{toluene}$ \\
         \hline
        \rule[-1mm]{0mm}{0.5cm}
         Equimolare & 0.497 & 0.365 & 0.137 & 0.170 & 0.242 & 0.588 \\
        \hline
        \rule[-1mm]{0mm}{0.5cm}
         Ricca in n-Esano & 0.893 & 0.078 & 0.029 & 0.609 & 0.108 & 0.283 \\
        \hline
        \rule[-1mm]{0mm}{0.5cm}
         Ricca in Toluene & 0.241 & 0.177 & 0.582 & 0.035 & 0.048 & 0.916 \\
        \hline
     \end{tabular}
      \caption{Composizione del syngas pre-quench}
    \label{tab:syngas_pre_quench }
\end{table}


Welcome to TeX.SE. Please make your code snippet complete, including the documentclass, usepackage statements, and begin/end document. This helps in making the issue reproducible and ensures that possible solutions will work for your situation as well.

Please provide a full MWE starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document} to make clear which document class and packages you use. Your issue is maybe related to cell colors, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65231/47927


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%% only used for the first example %%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

%%%% only used for the second example %%%%%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[wd=2.8cm] | *{3}{Q[wd=1.2cm]} | *{3}{Q[wd=1.2cm]} }, rowspec={|Q|Q|Q|Q|Q|}}
      \SetRow{gray8, font=\bfseries}  
      \SetCell[r=2]{m,2.8cm} Miscela  & \SetCell[c=3]{c} Fase vapore all'equilibrio &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} Fase liquida all'equilibrio \\ 
      \SetRow{gray8}
      & $y_\text{n-esano}$ & $y_\text{benzene}$ & $y_\text{toluene}$ & $x_\text{n-esano}$ & $x_\text{benzene}$ & $x_\text{toluene}$ \\
      Equimolare       & 0.497 & 0.365 & 0.137 & 0.170 & 0.242 & 0.588 \\
      Ricca in n-Esano & 0.893 & 0.078 & 0.029 & 0.609 & 0.108 & 0.283 \\
      Ricca in Toluene & 0.241 & 0.177 & 0.582 & 0.035 & 0.048 & 0.916 \\
    \end{tblr}
  \caption{Composizione del syngas pre-quench}
  \label{tab:syngas_pre_quench }
\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l *{6}{S[table-format=1.3]}} 
    \toprule
      Miscela  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Fase vapore all'equilibrio} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Fase liquida all'equilibrio} \\ 
      \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
      & $y_\text{n-esano}$ & $y_\text{benzene}$ & $y_\text{toluene}$ & $x_\text{n-esano}$ & $x_\text{benzene}$ & $x_\text{toluene}$ \\
      \midrule
      Equimolare       & 0.497 & 0.365 & 0.137 & 0.170 & 0.242 & 0.588 \\
      Ricca in n-Esano & 0.893 & 0.078 & 0.029 & 0.609 & 0.108 & 0.283 \\
      Ricca in Toluene & 0.241 & 0.177 & 0.582 & 0.035 & 0.048 & 0.916 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{Composizione del syngas pre-quench}
  \label{tab:syngas_pre_quench }
\end{table}



\end{document}


Here is a solution with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix. That environment is similar to the classical environment {tabular} (as defined by the package array) but provides new features.
In particular, the command \cline is redefined.
In the following code, I have replaced the environment {tabular} by an environment {NiceTabular} (and I have replaced \multicolumn{3}{c|} by \multicolumn{3}{c}).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{p{2.8cm} | p{1.2cm} p{1.2cm} p{1.2cm} | p{1.2cm} p{1.2cm} p{1cm}}
     \hline
     \rule[-1mm]{0mm}{0.5cm}
     \rowcolor{lightgray}
       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Fase vapore all'equilibrio}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Fase liquida all'equilibrio}} \\ 
       \cline{2-7}
         \rowcolor{lightgray}
         \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Miscela}}& $y_{n-esano}$ & $y_{benzene}$ & $y_{toluene}$ & $x_{n-esano}$ & $x_{benzene}$ & $x_{toluene}$ \\
         \hline
        \rule[-1mm]{0mm}{0.5cm}
         Equimolare & 0.497 & 0.365 & 0.137 & 0.170 & 0.242 & 0.588 \\
        \hline
        \rule[-1mm]{0mm}{0.5cm}
         Ricca in n-Esano & 0.893 & 0.078 & 0.029 & 0.609 & 0.108 & 0.283 \\
        \hline
        \rule[-1mm]{0mm}{0.5cm}
         Ricca in Toluene & 0.241 & 0.177 & 0.582 & 0.035 & 0.048 & 0.916 \\
        \hline
     \end{NiceTabular}
      \caption{Composizione del syngas pre-quench}
    \label{tab:syngas_pre_quench }
\end{table}

\end{document}



However, I recommend a design in the spirit of booktabs (see Leandriis' answer).
