# how to vertically align a cell in a table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a table that I define

```
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllll}
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img1.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img2.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img3.pdf} & 
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img4.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img5.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img6.pdf} \\
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img7.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img8.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img9.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img10.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img11.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img12.pdf} \\
\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{img13.pdf} & \multicolumn{12}{|c}{
\hspace{3cm} \includegraphics[width=92cm]{i3} }
\end{tabular}
```

Not all images are of the same height. I want all of the images to be aligned to the top of the tabular cell, instead of the bottom, which seems to be the case now.
How would I do that?

Comment: duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells/7227#7227

Comment: @xport: Thanks for adding the link. However, IMHO this question can be taken as a special case of the more general question you linked and can be solved with much less code.

Comment: Is it really just images or do you also have text? Especially multi-line text requires more work than when you have multiple images. It would be nice if you could rephrase your title if it's just about images.

Comment: `{lllllllllllll}` represents there are 13 columns. But the first and second rows has 6 columns each.

Comment: You are creating a poster? 7.3 inch / column x 6 columns x 2.54 cm = about 1.1 meter.

Comment: @kloop: I would recommend you to accept egreg's answer instead. Even if my very similar solution is the one you prefer for your specific document (a poster?), egreg's answer is the more correct one for the general case and would help others with the same issue more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only have images in the cells you can use `\raisebox` to vertical shift all images below the baseline, so that they all get top aligned

```
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=7.3in]{imgX.pdf}}
```

However, if you have text in the same row it will be placed just above the images (baseline is on the top corner). In that more complicated case see [How to vertically-center the text of the cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells/7227#7227).

Comment: PS: In the next release of `adjustbox` a new option `raise` for `\includegraphics` will be included, then you can use `\includegraphics[width=7.3in,raise=-\height]{imgX.pdf}` for short. I might also add a `align=t` or similar option which does the details for you.

Answer (score 5):

Use `\topincludegraphics` defined as follows

```
\newcommand{\topincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
```

instead of `\includegraphics`; without `\ht\strutbox` there would be gaps, because each table row is always at least as high as a strut.

Comment: +1 I didn't thought about the automatically added strut. (I did however plan to have an `align=t` and `align=T` (see my comment above) for exactly this two different cases; so actually I should have known better)

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newsavebox\topalignbox
\newcolumntype{T}{%
  >{\begin{lrbox}\topalignbox
    \rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}}
  c
  <{\end{lrbox}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}%
      {\usebox\topalignbox}}}

%%% or
%\newcolumntype{T}{%
%  >{\vtop\bgroup\vspace*{-\ht\strutbox}%
%    \hbox\bgroup\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}}
%  c
%  <{\egroup\egroup}}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tabular}{|T|T|} \hline
  \rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{4cm} \\ \hline
  \rule{4cm}{5cm} & \rule{2cm}{2cm} \\ \hline
  aabb & ccdd \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is somewhat complex. It is different with [xport's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/) since it ease the width calculation. The core code is the same as egreg's.

---

For vertical centering, it is better to use primitive TeX's `\vcenter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$\vcenter\bgroup\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup\egroup$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|M|M|} \hline
\rule{2cm}{3cm} & \rule{3cm}{4cm} \\ \hline
\rule{4cm}{5cm} & \rule{2cm}{2cm} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents on input line 15.`

Comment: IMHO this answer would be better suited for [How to vertically-center the text of the cells?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells). The idea was to have this similar question for the specific case of images with simpler answer and the linked question for the more complicated general case. (maybe I should merge the two question after all?)

Comment: BTW: you could use the `lrbox` environment to box the whole cell and then use `\raisebox` on it. But the trick is to aligned in right. The geometric center or top seems to be not "the correct" (TM) one.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I noticed that. But the result seems OK, I didn't pry `varwidth`'s code. `varwidth` here is certainly overused. I'm thinking about a new implementation.

Comment: @Martin: Indeed, I was answering vertically-center alignment question. After that I realized the origin question is asking for top alignment. I'll try `lrbox` or other method. And I want to get a general column type instead of egreg's `\topincludegraphics`.

Comment: `\newcolumntype{T}{>{\vtop\bgroup\vspace*{-\ht\strutbox}\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup\egroup}}`

Comment: @Leo: I'm looking forward to see your solution. It's just about were to put it. This question should be either merged with the other one or renamed to something like "How to top align images in a table?".

Comment: @Martin: Now updated solution uses `lrbox`. It works fine.

Comment: @greg: Good. I'll still add a `\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}` in the `\hbox` for plain text.

Comment: @Leo: Nice. A `\strut` should also do it instead of the `\rule`. I coded a `\collectbox{<code>}{<box content>}` macro in my `adjustbox` package which accepts the second "argument" also as `\bgroup .. \egroup` box. Once the new version is released you could use `>{\collectbox{\raisebox{..}{\BOXCONTENT}}\bgroup} .. <{\egroup}` or smaller using plainTeX macros:  `>{\collectbox{\raise\dimexpr ..\relax\BOXCONTENT}\bgroup} .. <{\egroup}`

Comment: @Martin: I use `\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}` instead of `\strut` to avoid extra depth. I didn't use your `ajustbox` but I tried `environ` package for this question, that isn't better than `lrbox` here.

Comment: @Leo: The extra depth should be an issue when its set together with the image in horizontal mode and the image is not shorter than that depth. Also `environ` doesn't work in tabular cells. You need to use `collcell` for that. It uses a very similar technique but specially for tabular cells. However, `lrbox` is much better here anyway! (and the new version of `adjustbox` which brings that feature isn't released yet)