# Tabular vertical alignment to top?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a simple tabular with two cells of text and two images below them like so:

```
\begin{tabular}[h]{ c | c}
    \emph{Normal} & \emph{Cone} \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{images/pipe1} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.61\textwidth]{images/pipe2}        
\end{tabular}
```

The first image is shorter than the second and I want it to be aligned at the top of the cell but for some reason it gets aligned to the **bottom** of the cell instead.

I've tried using the `array` package and do this:

```
\begin{tabular}[h]{ p{0.39\textwidth} | p{0.61\textwidth} }
    \emph{Normal} & \emph{Cone} \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{images/pipe1} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.61\textwidth]{images/pipe2}        
\end{tabular}
```

But this doesn't change anything. The first image is still aligned to the bottom.
Why is that?
Could there be something else going on which forces the alignment to stick to the bottom?

Comment: why not just call the two images with the same height instead of width?

Comment: "The first image is shorter than the second"

Comment: it doesn't matter since you're scaling them anyway.

Comment: See [how to vertically align a cell in a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22715/how-to-vertically-align-a-cell-in-a-table).

Comment: Does the `[t]` flag works in your case? `\begin{tabular}[t]{c|c} ... \end{tabular} `

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
\def\imagetop#1{\vtop{\null\hbox{#1}}}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
  \emph{Normal} & \emph{Cone} \\
  \imagetop{\includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{images/pipe1}}&
  \imagetop{\includegraphics[width=0.61\textwidth]{images/pipe1}}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide any insight on what's going on here though?

Comment: \def\imagetop#1{...} is the definition you need.
\vtop creates a verical box. This box contains two elements: an empty horizontal box (\null) and horizontal box with your picture. Also this box is aligned to the first empty horizontal box.

Comment: This does not seem to work when the object in the tabular is a tikzpicture. Ideas?

Comment: It works even inside an `\array` environment, inside the `$$` environment... I mean: `\begin{figure}[ht!];$\begin{array}{rl};\textnormal{(a)} & \imagetop{\includegraphics{...}}\\;\textnormal{(b)} & \imagetop{\includegraphics{...}};\end{array}$;\caption{\label{lbl}caption};\end{figure}` (the ";" stands for line break in the text!)

Comment: @AlexeyMalistov: Could you please also explain how to do this when you want to vertical align text to top?

Answer (score 7):

The topic has been discussed (and solved) in German here:
http://www.matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?topic=133671

In your case, try:

```
\begin{tabular}[h]{ c | c}
    \emph{Normal} & \emph{Cone} \\
    \raisebox{-\height+\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{images/pipe1}} &
    \raisebox{-\height+\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.61\textwidth]{images/pipe2}}
\end{tabular}
```

This should also solve the problem of the empty line above.

If you would like to stick with the `imagetop` command, try:

```
\def\imagetop#1{\raisebox{-\height+\baselineskip}{#1}}
```

Comment: Are you sure the link is right? All I can see is some guys discussing the fairly basic topic of what a `\baselineskip` is at a length I wouldn't have thought possible. Nothing about vertical alignment AFAICS.

Comment: Would be useful to mention that this needs `calc`. There's a tutorial here that explains it in detail: http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/publishing/latex_table_tips#align_the_top_of_a_figure_with_the_top_of_the_text_in_a_table_row

Answer (score 6):

Regarding WLanger's question about Alexey's solution: to adjust for the empty line on top of the image, put the text into a \parbox, and use \raisebox (with a negative value) to adjust it's vertical position.

```
\raisebox{value}{your text here} % will lower text if it has a negative value.

\parbox{width}{your text here} % will allow for text wrapping
```

You will have to nest them, like this:

```
\raisebox{value}{\parbox{width}{your text goes here}}
```

So the result will be this:

```
\def\imagetop#1{\vtop{\null\hbox{#1}}}

\begin{tabular}[h]{c|c}        
  \emph{Normal} & \emph{Cone} \\        
  \imagetop{\includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{images/pipe1}} & \raisebox{-1cm}{\parbox{8cm}{Replace this with your text, and adjust the raisebox and parbox values to your liking. I don't know the measurements of the images you're using or I'd do it for you.}
  \imagetop{\includegraphics[width=0.61\textwidth]{images/pipe1}}
\end{tabular}
```

It isn't elegant, but it works!