# Align text from top in tabularx

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I have a problem in alignment of text in `tabularx` environment

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,top=2cm,includehead,headsep=0.6cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{University of Toronto Sample Indicators for Investigation Skills}
\label{tab2}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{.5\textwidth}{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{6}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\textbf{02B Collect existing information}& No information collected &Information collected covers few/no important concepts or relevant prior work in research area.&Information collected covers some important concepts and relevant prior work in research area. &Information collected covers most important concepts and relevant prior work in research area.& Information collected covers all important concepts and relevant prior work in research area. \\
&&Information collected is not at all credible &Information collected is somewhat credible. &Information collected is mostly credible. &Information collected is entirely credible. \\
\textbf{02C Perform a pedagogical review of a research paper or article} &Review does not contextualize the article. &Review contextualizes the article incorrectly or superficially.   &Review contextualizes the article ineffectively.   &Review contextualizes the article. &Review contextualizes the article very effectively. \\
&No identification of: ☐ trends and patterns ☐ gaps in article ☐ major findings related to research questions &Incorrect identification of: ☐ trends and patterns ☐ gaps in article ☐ major findings related research questions &   Minimal identification of: ☐ trends and patterns ☐ gaps in article ☐ learnings to research questions&   Sufficient identification of: ☐ trends and patterns ☐ gaps in article ☐ learnings to research questions&    Comprehensive identification of: ☐ trends and patterns ☐ gaps in article ☐ learnings to research questions \\
\textbf{02D Perform a critical review of a research paper or article}&☐ No summary provided ☐ No key ideas captured &☐ Summary is incorrect ☐ Incorrect ideas captured&☐ Summary is marginally sufficient  ☐ Some key ideas missing &☐ Summary is complete ☐ Captures key ideas of the article &☐ Summary demonstrates substantial depth of understanding ☐ All key ideas emphasized\\
&☐ Criticism of key components not covered &Criticism of key components: ☐ incorrectly covered ☐ complete lack of insight &Criticism of key components: ☐ missing some key components ☐are superficial &Criticism of key components: ☐ mostly covered ☐ shows sufficient insight&Criticism of key components: ☐ exceptionally well covered ☐ are insightful \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I want to have a table like this:

[image]

The problem is alignment of text from top.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103601/top-alignment-of-cell-content-in-tabularx solves your problem? Or you don't want something like this?

Comment: If you just want the contents of your cells to be aligned at the top, you simply need to remove or comment out the following line `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}` from your code. For single cells spreading over two rows (as shown in the example image, first column), you can have a look at the `multirow` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
%\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggested solution, which is due to some manual adjustment of lenghts and heights definitely not the most elegant solution possible. The original idea of using enumitem for a list with checkboxes is borrowed from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247688/134144

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,top=2cm,includehead,headsep=0.6cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\newlist{todolisttop}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$,noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip}}
\setlist[todolisttop]{label=$\square$,noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr0.58\baselineskip},after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htb]
\def\arraystretch{2}
   \noindent
\centering
\caption{University of Toronto Sample Indicators for Investigation Skills}
\label{tab2}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{6}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
\textbf{02B Collect existing information}& 
\begin{todolisttop}\item No information collected \end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Information collected covers few/no important concepts or relevant prior work in research area.\end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Information collected covers some important concepts and relevant prior work in research area. \end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Information collected covers most important concepts and relevant prior work in research area.\end{todolisttop}& 
\begin{todolisttop}\item Information collected covers all important concepts and relevant prior work in research area. \end{todolisttop} \\

&&\begin{todolisttop}\item Information collected is not at all credible \end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Information collected is somewhat credible. \end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Information collected is mostly credible. \end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Information collected is entirely credible. \end{todolisttop}\\
\midrule

\multirow{2}[0]{\hsize}[-0.7\normalbaselineskip]{\textbf{02C Perform a  pedagogical review of  a research paper or article}} &
%\textbf{02C Perform a  pedagogical review of  a research paper or article} &
Review does not contextualize the article. &
Review contextualizes the article incorrectly or superficially.   &
Review contextualizes the article ineffectively.   &
Review contextualizes the article. &
Review contextualizes the article very effectively. \\
&No identification of: \begin{todolist}\item trends and patterns \item gaps in article \item major findings related to research questions \end{todolist}&
Incorrect identification of: \begin{todolist}\item trends and patterns \item gaps in article \item major findings related research questions \end{todolist}&   
Minimal identification of: \begin{todolist}\item trends and patterns \item gaps in article \item learnings to research questions \end{todolist}&   
Sufficient identification of: \begin{todolist}\item trends and patterns \item gaps in article \item learnings to research questions \end{todolist}&
Comprehensive identification of: \begin{todolist}\item trends and patterns \item gaps in article \item learnings to research questions\end{todolist} \\
\midrule

\textbf{02D Perform a critical review of a research paper or article}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item  No summary provided \item No key ideas captured \end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Summary is incorrect \item Incorrect ideas captured \end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Summary is marginally sufficient  \item Some key ideas missing \end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Summary is complete \item Captures key ideas of the article \end{todolisttop}&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Summary demonstrates substantial depth of understanding \item All key ideas emphasized \end{todolisttop}\\
&
\begin{todolisttop}\item Criticism of key components not covered \end{todolisttop}&
Criticism of key components: \begin{todolist}\item incorrectly covered \item complete lack of insight \end{todolist}&
Criticism of key components: \begin{todolist}\item missing some key components \item are superficial \end{todolist}&
Criticism of key components: \begin{todolist}\item mostly covered \item  shows sufficient insight \end{todolist}&
Criticism of key components: \begin{todolist}\item \hspace{0pt}exceptionally well covered \item are insightful \end{todolist}\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]