# Latex table cell linebreaks expands to whole row

Tags: tables, line-breaking, cell

I have this table, and making `\\`  line breaks in first column, but this affects also the next cell, which is unintended. How can i stop this behavior? I have tried a lot, at this point, but i feel like im trying in blindness.

The src for the table:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Analyse for processor - kandidat muligheder}
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c| P{0.9\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Kandidater\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Argumentation og opstillet forsøg\end{tabular}}}  
\\ \hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[p]{@{}c@{}} \\
Qualcomm \\
QCC5100 \\ 
Series\cite{Qualcomm_LE_audio_chip_series} \end{tabular}}}

& 
Den første kandidat vi har fundet er en serie af chips fra Qualcomm, der bygger på ARM arkitektur. Hvis vi tager udgangspunkt i den chip i serien som er har bedste performance QCC5181 \cite{Qualcomm_LE_audio_chip_series}. Chippen er en quad-core processor arkitektur, som består af en to cores CPU processor og 2 single cores DSP'er. QCC5181 chippens specs er følgende:
\begin{itemize}
    \item 80 MHz CPU
    \item 2x 240 MHz DSP
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Flash: 1 MB
        \item 384 KB program RAM 
        \item 1408 KB data RAM 
        \item Floating-point unit(FPU)
        \item DSP instruction capabilities
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
Generelt er det svært at få information eller datablade om chippen da man skal være oprettet medlem og som registreret virksomhed. Det samme gælder for at kunne arbejde med deres development boards. Men vi har valgt at nævne denne mulighed på trods, da de opfylder vores mimumskrav og ville være en ideal kandidat. Men grundet development boardet er svært tilgængeligt for private på nuværende tidspunkt, så går vi ikke videre med denne kandidat.
\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\\ Nordic \\ Semiconductor \\S \\ nRF5340 \cite{NordicSemi_LE_audio_chip} \\ \\ nRF5340 \\ Audio DK \cite{NordicSemi_LE_audio_chip_developmentboard} \end{tabular}}} 

& Den anden kandidat vi har fundet er en chip fra Nordic Semiconductor, der er en alt i en SoC, som består af to ARM-Cortex-M33 processorer, Bluetooth 5.3 som understøtter BLE og single cycle 32×32-bit multiplier. nRF5340 chippens specs er følgende: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item 128/64 MHz Arm Cortex-M33
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Flash: 1 MB
        \item 512 KB RAM
        \item Floating-point unit(FPU)
        \item DSP instruction capabilities
        \item Ved 128 MHz, så opnåes en benchmark på 514 CoreMark ved 66 CoreMark/mA.
    \end{itemize}
    \item 64 MHz Arm Cortex-M33
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Flash: 256 KB
        \item 64 KB RAM
        \item Dedikeret til networking
        \item Ved 64 MHz, så opnåes en benchmark på 257 CoreMark at 73 CoreMark/mA.
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

Nordic Semiconductor sælger også et development board, nRF5340 Audio DK, hvor på der også er adgang til en DSP. Ydermere har de god support og et R\&D fællesskab omhandlende chippen og boardet. De har en dokumentation hjemmeside, som guider dig igennem opsætning og installering og redigering af software, samt tilhørende Youtube videoer. På baggrund af dette, vil vi gå videre med denne kandidat. Til et proof of concept, så vil vi vi prøve at implementere det filter som vi tidligere har testet.
\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please always make sure examples are full bit minimal examples, not sniplets where others will have to add code in order to test the sniplet provided. Most people here will just pass on such a question.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this  `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Kandidater\end{tabular}}` `\textbf{Kandidater}` ought to be enough.

Comment: A `p` column needs a mandatory argument which specifies the width

Comment: Please tell us how or where the `P` column type is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this table is a very good candidate for using a `tabularx` environment.

Observe the use of the options `[noitemsep]` and `[nosep]` for the itemize-like environments, to save quite a bit of vertical whitespace. On the other hand, the `adjustbox` machinery is no longer used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern} % or some other suitable font package

%new:
\usepackage{booktabs,enumitem,tabularx,ragged2e,amsmath}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{{\bfseries\smash[b]{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\caption{Analyse for processor - kandidat muligheder\strut}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c >{\RaggedRight}X @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Kandidater} & \textbf{Argumentation og opstillet forsøg} \\ 
\midrule 

\mytab{Qualcomm \\
  QCC5100 \\ 
  Series \cite{Qualcomm_LE_audio_chip_series}}
& 
Den første kandidat vi har fundet er en serie af chips fra Qualcomm, der bygger på ARM arkitektur. Hvis vi tager udgangspunkt i den chip i serien som er har bedste performance QCC5181 \cite{Qualcomm_LE_audio_chip_series}. Chippen er en quad-core processor arkitektur, som består af en to cores CPU processor og 2 single cores DSP'er. QCC5181 chippens specs er følgende:
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep] % <-- 'noitemsep'
    \item 80 MHz CPU
    \item 2x 240 MHz DSP
        \begin{itemize}[nosep] % <-- 'nosep'
        \item Flash: 1 MB
        \item 384 KB program RAM 
        \item 1408 KB data RAM 
        \item Floating-point unit(FPU)
        \item DSP instruction capabilities
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
Generelt er det svært at få information eller datablade om chippen da man skal være oprettet medlem og som registreret virksomhed. Det samme gælder for at kunne arbejde med deres development boards. Men vi har valgt at nævne denne mulighed på trods, da de opfylder vores mimumskrav og ville være en ideal kandidat. Men grundet development boardet er svært tilgængeligt for private på nuværende tidspunkt, så går vi ikke videre med denne kandidat.
\\ 

\midrule

\mytab{Nordic \\ 
       Semiconductor \\
       S \\ 
       nRF5340 \cite{NordicSemi_LE_audio_chip} \\ 
       \\ 
       nRF5340 \\ 
       Audio DK \cite{NordicSemi_LE_audio_chip_developmentboard}}

& Den anden kandidat vi har fundet er en chip fra Nordic Semiconductor, der er en alt i en SoC, som består af to ARM-Cortex-M33 processorer, Bluetooth 5.3 som understøtter BLE og single cycle 32×32-bit multiplier. nRF5340 chippens specs er følgende: 
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep] % <-- 'noitemsep'
    \item 128/64 MHz Arm Cortex-M33
    \begin{itemize}[nosep] % <-- 'nosep'
        \item Flash: 1 MB
        \item 512 KB RAM
        \item Floating-point unit(FPU)
        \item DSP instruction capabilities
        \item Ved 128 MHz, så opnåes en benchmark på 514 CoreMark ved 66 CoreMark/mA.
    \end{itemize}
    \item 64 MHz Arm Cortex-M33
    \begin{itemize}[nosep] % <-- 'nosep'
        \item Flash: 256 KB
        \item 64 KB RAM
        \item Dedikeret til networking
        \item Ved 64 MHz, så opnåes en benchmark på 257 CoreMark at 73 CoreMark/mA.
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
Nordic Semiconductor sælger også et development board, nRF5340 Audio DK, hvor på der også er adgang til en DSP. Ydermere har de god support og et R\&D fællesskab omhandlende chippen og boardet. De har en dokumentation hjemmeside, som guider dig igennem opsætning og installering og redigering af software, samt tilhørende Youtube videoer. På baggrund af dette, vil vi gå videre med denne kandidat. Til et proof of concept, så vil vi vi prøve at implementere det filter som vi tidligere har testet.
\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The alignment of the `tabular` environment in the first column and the text in the second column is controlled by the alignment option of the `tabular` environment. You've used `[p]` and `[c]` as alignment options. To align the two columns at the top, the option should be `[t]` (`\begin{tabular}[t]`). I believe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103601/top-alignment-of-cell-content-in-tabularx) is a similar problem.

I've modified your table so that the text is aligned at the top (I've changed the column type from `P` to `p` since I don't know your definition of this column type).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Analyse for processor - kandidat muligheder}
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c| p{0.9\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Kandidater\end{tabular}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Argumentation og opstillet forsøg\end{tabular}}}  
\\ \hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} \\
Qualcomm \\
QCC5100 \\ 
Series\cite{Qualcomm_LE_audio_chip_series} \end{tabular}}}

& 
Den første kandidat vi har fundet er en serie af chips fra Qualcomm, der bygger på ARM arkitektur. Hvis vi tager udgangspunkt i den chip i serien som er har bedste performance QCC5181 \cite{Qualcomm_LE_audio_chip_series}. Chippen er en quad-core processor arkitektur, som består af en to cores CPU processor og 2 single cores DSP'er. QCC5181 chippens specs er følgende:
\begin{itemize}
    \item 80 MHz CPU
    \item 2x 240 MHz DSP
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Flash: 1 MB
        \item 384 KB program RAM 
        \item 1408 KB data RAM 
        \item Floating-point unit(FPU)
        \item DSP instruction capabilities
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
Generelt er det svært at få information eller datablade om chippen da man skal være oprettet medlem og som registreret virksomhed. Det samme gælder for at kunne arbejde med deres development boards. Men vi har valgt at nævne denne mulighed på trods, da de opfylder vores mimumskrav og ville være en ideal kandidat. Men grundet development boardet er svært tilgængeligt for private på nuværende tidspunkt, så går vi ikke videre med denne kandidat.
\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\\ Nordic \\ Semiconductor \\S \\ nRF5340 \cite{NordicSemi_LE_audio_chip} \\ \\ nRF5340 \\ Audio DK \cite{NordicSemi_LE_audio_chip_developmentboard} \end{tabular}}} 

& Den anden kandidat vi har fundet er en chip fra Nordic Semiconductor, der er en alt i en SoC, som består af to ARM-Cortex-M33 processorer, Bluetooth 5.3 som understøtter BLE og single cycle 32×32-bit multiplier. nRF5340 chippens specs er følgende: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item 128/64 MHz Arm Cortex-M33
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Flash: 1 MB
        \item 512 KB RAM
        \item Floating-point unit(FPU)
        \item DSP instruction capabilities
        \item Ved 128 MHz, så opnåes en benchmark på 514 CoreMark ved 66 CoreMark/mA.
    \end{itemize}
    \item 64 MHz Arm Cortex-M33
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Flash: 256 KB
        \item 64 KB RAM
        \item Dedikeret til networking
        \item Ved 64 MHz, så opnåes en benchmark på 257 CoreMark at 73 CoreMark/mA.
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

Nordic Semiconductor sælger også et development board, nRF5340 Audio DK, hvor på der også er adgang til en DSP. Ydermere har de god support og et R\&D fællesskab omhandlende chippen og boardet. De har en dokumentation hjemmeside, som guider dig igennem opsætning og installering og redigering af software, samt tilhørende Youtube videoer. På baggrund af dette, vil vi gå videre med denne kandidat. Til et proof of concept, så vil vi vi prøve at implementere det filter som vi tidligere har testet.
\\

\hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Note: An alternative approach for line breaks in a cell is suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell) with the `makecell` package.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `tabularray` package (as usual :-)), `siunitx` for writing quantities and `microtype` for nicer fit text in `X` table column and omit vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

%new:
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % or some other suitable font package
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0.5ex, 
                  noitemsep,
                  leftmargin=2em,
                  }
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=--}

\caption{Analyse for processor - kandidat muligheder}

\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[c, font=\bfseries] X[j] @{}},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
             measure = vbox,
             % vlines   % in the case if yiz prefer vertical linens ...
             }
    \toprule
Kandidater  &   Argumentation og opstillet forsøg   \\
    \midrule
{Qualcomm \\
 QCC5100 \\
 Series \cite{Qualcomm_LE_audio_chip_series}}
    &   Den første kandidat vi har fundet er en serie af chips fra Qualcomm, der bygger på ARM arkitektur. Hvis vi tager udgangspunkt i den chip i serien som er har bedste performance QCC5181 \cite{Qualcomm_LE_audio_chip_series}. Chippen er en quad-core processor arkitektur, som består af en to cores CPU processor og 2 single cores DSP'er. QCC5181 chippens specs er følgende:
    \begin{itemize} % <-- 'noitemsep'
        \item \qty{80}{\MHz} CPU
        \item $2\times \qty{240}{\MHz}$ DSP
            \begin{itemize}
            \item Flash: \qty{1}{MB}
            \item \qty{384}{KB} program RAM
            \item \qty{1408}{KB} data RAM
            \item Floating-point unit(FPU)
            \item DSP instruction capabilities
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
Generelt er det svært at få information eller datablade om chippen da man skal være oprettet medlem og som registreret virksomhed. Det samme gælder for at kunne arbejde med deres development boards. Men vi har valgt at nævne denne mulighed på trods, da de opfylder vores mimumskrav og ville være en ideal kandidat. Men grundet development boardet er svært tilgængeligt for private på nuværende tidspunkt, så går vi ikke videre med denne kandidat.
\\
    \midrule
{Nordic \\
 Semiconductor \\
 S \\
 nRF5340 \cite{NordicSemi_LE_audio_chip}    \\
 \  \\
 nRF5340 \\
 Audio DK \cite{NordicSemi_LE_audio_chip_developmentboard}
 }
    &   Den anden kandidat vi har fundet er en chip fra Nordic Semiconductor, der er en alt i en SoC, som består af to ARM-Cortex-M33 processorer, Bluetooth 5.3 som understøtter BLE og single cycle $32\times 32$-bit multiplier. nRF5340 chippens specs er følgende:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \qty[parse-numbers=false]{128/64}{MHz} Arm Cortex-M33
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Flash: \qty{1}{MB}
                    \item \qty{512}{KB} RAM
                    \item Floating-point unit(FPU)
                    \item DSP instruction capabilities
                    \item Ved \qty{128}{MHz}, så opnåes en benchmark på 514 CoreMark ved 66 CoreMark/mA.
                \end{itemize}
            \item \qty{64}{MHz} Arm Cortex-M33
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Flash: \qty{256}{KB}
                \item \qty{64}{KB} RAM
                \item Dedikeret til networking
                \item Ved \qty{64}{MHz}, så opnåes en benchmark på 257 CoreMark at 73 CoreMark/mA.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
        Nordic Semiconductor sælger også et development board, nRF5340 Audio DK, hvor på der også er adgang til en DSP. Ydermere har de god support og et R\&D fællesskab omhandlende chippen og boardet. De har en dokumentation hjemmeside, som guider dig igennem opsætning og installering og redigering af software, samt tilhørende Youtube videoer. På baggrund af dette, vil vi gå videre med denne kandidat. Til et proof of concept, så vil vi vi prøve at implementere det filter som vi tidligere har testet.
        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]