# Image with caption on the right, vertical align the caption to the top edge of the image

Tags: tables, graphics, captions, minipage, includegraphics

So far I tried two Ansatzes using (i) minipage and (ii) tabular environment:

```
%(i) minipage
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \includegraphics{figures/general_model/dummy}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \caption{ This is the caption to my dummy figure. It is very informative. I like rainy weather. I am too lazy to include lorem lipsum.} \label{fig:segments}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

and

```
%(ii) tabular
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.45\textwidth}}
    \vspace{0pt} 
    \includegraphics{figures/general_model/dummy}
    & 
    \vspace{0pt}
    \caption{ This is the caption to my dummy figure. It is very informative. I like rainy weather. I am too lazy to include lorem lipsum.}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

Both yield the same behavior:

[image]

I have been drawing the red dotted line manually to mark the top edge of the image.

How can I align the caption with the top edge of the image like so:

[image]

I would prefer answers using tabular or minipage and avoid including new libraries.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [tables - tabular vertical alignment to top? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23521/tabular-vertical-alignment-to-top) ?

Comment: The issue is the `\abovecaptionskip` moving your caption downwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like was mentioned in the comments by [Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon), setting `abovecaptionskip` does the trick, for both environments:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \includegraphics{figures/general_model/dummy}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt} 
        \caption{ This is the caption to my dummy figure. It is very informative. I like rainy weather. I am too lazy to include lorem lipsum.} \label{fig:segments}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `tabularray`, `adjustbox`  and `caption` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % for "valign",  also load graphicx
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}   % <===
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[c] X[j,t]}}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    &   \captionsetup{skip=-\abovecaptionskip}
        \caption{\lipsum[1][2-4].}
        \end{minipage}
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without any packages, the following defines an environment called `sidecap` that takes an optional argument and a mandatory one (just like `\caption`) and will typeset the caption to the right of the contents of the environment. The caption will get as much space as there is left on the line with a customizable separation of the length `\sidecap@sep`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\sidecap@box
\newlength\sidecap@sep
\setlength\sidecap@sep{10pt}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {sidecap} { O{#2} m }
  {%
    \begin{lrbox}{\sidecap@box}%
  }
  {%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \mbox
      {%
        \raisebox{-\height}{\usebox\sidecap@box}%
        \hskip\sidecap@sep
        \raisebox{-\height}
          {%
            \setlength\abovecaptionskip\z@
            \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\sidecap@box-\sidecap@sep}%
              {\caption[{#1}]{#2}}%
          }%
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage{duckuments}% <- dummy content

\begin{document}
\blindduck[full]
\begin{figure}
  \begin{sidecap}{A lovely duck.\label{fig:duck}}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
  \end{sidecap}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{sidecap}{Another lovely duck for which I need to tell you so much that
    my caption will get a bit too long to fit in a single line.\label{fig:ducky}}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
  \end{sidecap}
\end{figure}
\blindduck[full]
\end{document}
```

First float:

[image]

Second float:

[image]