# Vertical centered image in cell

Tags: tables, graphics

Consider following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\paperheight297mm
\paperwidth210mm

\textheight297mm
\textwidth180mm

\topmargin-25.4mm
\voffset0in
\oddsidemargin-17.5mm
\evensidemargin-17.5mm
\hoffset0in

\marginparsep0in
\marginparwidth0in

\headheight0in
\headsep0in

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{green}{pink}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{60mm} p{60mm} p{60mm}}
\includegraphics[height=40mm]{test.png} & 2 & 3 \\[50.8mm]
\includegraphics[height=40mm]{test.png} & 2 & 3 \\[50.8mm]
\includegraphics[height=40mm]{test.png} & 2 & 3 \\[50.8mm]
\includegraphics[height=40mm]{test.png} & 2 & 3 \\[50.8mm]
\includegraphics[height=40mm]{test.png} & 2 & 3 \\[50.8mm]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The images are changing the height of the cells. How can I prevent this and how can I vertically center the images?

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[top=0pt,bottom=0pt,textwidth=180mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{green}{pink}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{p{60mm-2\tabcolsep}}}
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=40mm,width=50mm]{logo}} & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Your code ends in an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.<argument> 
\includegraphics[height=40mm,width=50mm]{logo} ...udegraphics[height=40mm,width=50mm]{logo}}
```

Comment: See for example [How to vertically-center the text of the cells?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells/7227) and [How to vertically align a cell in a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22715/how-to-vertically-align-a-cell-in-a-table).

Comment: Could you add a picture of the output?

Comment: I´ll try this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4693/is-there-a-good-document-template-for-making-business-cards

Answer (score 3):

The reference point of an image is at the bottom of its bounding box; with `adjustbox` you can specify a different vertical alignment. Note also the usage of `calc` to really get the desired width of the table; I used `geometry` in order to avoid complicated calculations for the page dimensions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[top=0pt,bottom=0pt,textwidth=180mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{green}{pink}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{p{60mm-2\tabcolsep}}}
\includegraphics[height=40mm,width=50mm,valign=c]{test.png} & 2 & 3 \\
\includegraphics[height=40mm,width=50mm,valign=c]{test.png} & 2 & 3 \\
\includegraphics[height=40mm,width=50mm,valign=c]{test.png} & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that `adjustbox` with the `export` option loads the `graphicx` package.

Without `adjustbox` you get the same effect with

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=40mm,width=50mm]{test.png}} & 2 & 3 \
```

(of course loading `graphicx` is necessary).

Comment: I don't have the adjustbox package. I work on ubuntu and use Texmaker. How do I get this package?
I tried it so far with this: \raisebox{-\height}[10mm]{\includegraphics[height=40mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}[10mm]{Test} & 2 & 3 \\[50.8mm]
It works almost, except it changes the height of the cell...