# Vertical centering of text spanning multiple rows

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to vertically-center the text of the cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells)

I am using multicolumn to create a table. The code that I have is here:

```
   \documentclass[10pt]{article} 
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \begin{document}
     \begin{table}
       \centering
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
       \hline
       \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Data A} & Data B \\\cline{1-2}
       Set A1 & Set A2 &  
       \\\hline
       a & b & c \\
       \hline
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{List of test cases.}
       \label{tab:Tests}
     \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This results in a table where the entry 'Data B' is aligned with the top hline of the table as in [image: this].

I would like to know how I can vertically center the entry ''Data B''. Any ideas would help a lot!

Comment: Not related to your question, but check out the `booktabs` package and the discussion regarding vertical lines in its manual.

Comment: You are loading but not using the `multicol` package in your MWE (it is unrelated to tables and is for making multi-column _pages_) the `\multicolumn` command doesn't require a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `multirow`.

```
   \documentclass[10pt]{article} 
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}
     \begin{table}
       \centering
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
       \hline
       \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Data A} & \multirow{2}{*}{Data B} \\\cline{1-2}
       Set A1 & Set A2 &  
       \\\hline
       a & b & c \\
       \hline
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{List of test cases.}
       \label{tab:Tests}
     \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]