# How to align a tabular cell right and centre?

Tags: tables

I've vertically centered a column of headings as suggested in an answer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells) using `array` and `m{}`. How can I also right-align those headings?

Here is a picture of my current table and the results:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\centering%
    \def\tinySubWidth{2.5cm}
    \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{\tinySubWidth}m{\tinySubWidth}m{\tinySubWidth}m{\tinySubWidth}}
        &
        \centering Column 1&
        \centering Column 2&
        \centering Column 3&
        Column 4
        \\
        The first row heading%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}\\
        The second row heading%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}\\
        The third row heading%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}\\
        The fourth row heading%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Bla}
    \label{fig:res-axvel-latax}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `>{...}` syntax to set the column to be `\raggedleft` (or `\RaggedLeft` if the `ragged2e` package is loaded):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\centering%
    \def\tinySubWidth{2.5cm}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}m{2cm}m{\tinySubWidth}m{\tinySubWidth}m{\tinySubWidth}m{\tinySubWidth}}
        &
        \centering Column 1&
        \centering Column 2&
        \centering Column 3&
        Column 4
        \\
        The first row heading%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}\\
        The second row heading%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}\\
        The third row heading%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}\\
        The fourth row heading%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}%
        &\includegraphics[width=\tinySubWidth]{path}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Bla}
    \label{fig:res-axvel-latax}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]