# \Huge Text in Tabular touches table border

Tags: tables, fontsize

If I want different font sizes within a table, how do I prevent the text from touching table borders? And why is it touching the table border in the first place?

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\mycoordinates}
{
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|} \hline
\Huge Point & \Huge Original \(\rightarrow\) Transformed \\ \hline 
\Huge A & \\ \hline
B & \\ \hline
C & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\mycoordinates

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\extrarowheight` or see `booktabs` or `makecell` or add additional spacing manually at the end of the row or ... ?

Comment: Ok, I will try those things.

Comment: Why would `tabular`'s default NOT give enough space to the contents of the cell? Even in row B and C of the picture, there is more space underneath the text than above. Why? And is there some place I can learn all of these defaults?

Comment: the default is normal line spacing (basically the height and depth of `\strut`   so the space below is the normal depth to make room for `\normalsize` descenders, the fact that the capital letters are closer to the top than that is just a feature of the font design and the baseline spacing chosen to go with it, essentially (without the `\hline`) you would see the same spacing in paragraph text

Comment: You could read `booktabs`'s manual which has quite a lot to say about this in general, even if not in particular.

Comment: and you are missing `%` from ends of lines in your definition.

Comment: @cfr you mean that small fraction of the manual not berating the reader for even thinking of using a vertical rule in a table:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle: *Castigat non ridendo mores!*

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Probably only part of that part, but I was indeed thinking of somewhere in that small part, yes. It does have the virtue of clarity despite the overall tone of hysteria, after all.

Answer (score 5):

LaTeX tables are generally very tight. You can play with `\arraystretch` but in this case (different font sizes  for different rows) it may not be very easy.

Two packages can tackle this problem, each with its own limitations:

- `cellspace` defines *minimal* distances between cell contents and  the row above or the row below. All you have to do is define these minimal distances, and prefix the relevant columns specifiers with the letter `S` (or `C` if you use `siunitx`).
- `makecell` can *add* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells. You have to set this spacing, then use the command `\makegapedcells`.

Another solution is to give up all vertical rules, to have a more professional looking table, and replace `\hline\s and`\cline`s with the`\toprule`, \midrule`, `\cmidrule` and `\bottomrule` commands from `booktabs`, which introduces somme vertical padding around these rules.

Here are examples of these solutions. You'll find more details in the documentations of the packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace} 
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\mycoordinates}
{
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sl|} \hline
\Huge Point & \Huge Original \(\rightarrow\) Transformed \\ \hline
\Huge A & \\ \hline
B & \\ \hline
C & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\mycoordinates
\vskip 1cm

{\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|} \hline
\Huge Point & \Huge Original \(\rightarrow\) Transformed \\ \hline
\Huge A & \\ \hline
B & \\ \hline
C & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\vskip 1cm

\begin{tabular}{cl} \toprule
\Huge Point & \Huge Original \(\rightarrow\) Transformed \\ 
\midrule
\Huge A & \\ 
\midrule
B & \\ 
\midrule
C & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX uses a `\strut` for setting the cell's height; however the `\strut` is computed before starting the table.

Just add a `\strut` after `\Huge` (one cell in the row where `\Huge` appears suffices).

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|l|} \hline
\Huge \strut Point & \Huge Original \(\rightarrow\) Transformed \\ \hline
\Huge \strut A & \\ \hline
B & \\ \hline
C & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is probably simplest to set up the table for `\Huge` and just have smaller text where needed. (option (b))

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\mycoordinates}
{\par
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|} \hline
\Huge Point & \Huge Original \(\rightarrow\) Transformed \\ \hline 
\Huge A & \\ \hline
B & \\ \hline
C & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%%
}
\newcommand{\mycoordinatesb}
{{\par\Huge
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|} \hline
Point &  Original \(\rightarrow\) Transformed \\ \hline 
 A & \\ \hline
\normalsize B & \\ \hline
\normalsize C & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%%
}}
\newcommand{\mycoordinatesc}
{{\setlength\extrarowheight{17pt}\par
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|} \hline
\Huge Point & \Huge Original \(\rightarrow\) Transformed \\ \hline 
\Huge A & \\ \hline
B & \\ \hline
C & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%%
}}
\newcommand{\mycoordinatesd}
{{\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}\par
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|} \hline
\Huge Point & \Huge Original \(\rightarrow\) Transformed \\ \hline 
\Huge A & \\ \hline
B & \\ \hline
C & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%%
}}


\begin{document}

\mycoordinates
\mycoordinatesb
\mycoordinatesc
\mycoordinatesd

\end{document}
```