# rotatebox with [origin=c] destroys tabular

Tags: graphics, xepersian

When I using`[origin=c]`, the tabular is corrupted.

and all the next table's was destroyed.

`xepersian` is a package for bidirectional writing (with `XeLaTex`).

If I enable ‍`\setLTR`, the problem is solved.

**I want the text vertically centred in cell.**

please help me. thanks

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
\setLTR

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 
\rotatebox{90}{my longer text}  & \rotatebox{90}{my text} 
\\ \hline 
21 & 22  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10mm}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{my longer text} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{my text} 
\\ \hline 
21 & 22  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10mm}

\setRTL

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{my longer text} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{my text} 
\\ \hline 
21 & 22  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 
11 & 12 
\\ \hline 
21 & 22  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: in \setLTR enabled mode (without xepersian)]

[image]

I have attached two photos.

pic 1: I enable `\setLTR`. (text in LTR mode). and i dont have problem.

pic 2: I enable `\setRTL` (default of xepersian package). and tabular 3,4 were hidden.

Comment: I was about to suggest to remove the [origin=c] command because the text will be centred anyway, only to receive "text my" in the table. Is that intended behaviour?

Comment: @Huang_d
i want to center my text with orogin=c. in this example:
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 
\rotatebox{90}{my longer text}  & \rotatebox{90}{my text} 
\\ \hline 
21 & 22  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
i want to (my text) is centered with origin=c
and hiding the tabular, to be solved.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, you want the text vertically centred? The `[origin=c]` is the point around which the text is rotated. Within the `tabular` environment, the text is then shifted horizontally to the centre. So from my understanding, `[origin=c]` wound give the same result as `[origin=b]` or no specification. For vertical centring, have a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells  If I misunderstand you, please clarify.

Comment: @HadiSafiaghdam 
put \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{my text} in \lr or \LRE. this solves your problem, but I've no idea why it cannot be typeset out of LTR environment.

Comment: @Huang_d
thanks. Yes I want the text vertically centred.
if i disable xepersian package or enable \setLTR, it is ok. and (my text) is centered. 
but if i enable xepersian package, The problem appears. and content of tabular and some lines are hidden. (picture 2)
I want to work in the RTL text, as in Latin works (without mistake)
i edit my question

Comment: @javadr
thanks. but, I wrote that :
If I enable ‍\setLTR, the problem is solved.
I like the basic solution.