# Top and bottom space fixing in table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

My code are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|l}
Test &Trial\\
Trial &Test\\
& Test
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Vertical rule should be on the exact top and bottom of the table, is it possible to fix? Please advise...

[image]

Comment: is it something to do with centered cell alignment? if so, this might help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells

Comment: @Raaja Thanks for your suggestion, but it was not help me to meet the requirement, anyway, thanks a lot....

Comment: Can you please tell what's the use of this?

Answer (score 3):

This "misalignment" is due to the linespace of your document. 
You could decrease the space be putting the table in a spacing environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

Before:

\begin{tabular}{c|l}
\hline
Test &Trial\\
Trial &Test\\
& Test \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


After:

\begin{spacing}{0.5}
 \begin{tabular}{c|l}
    \hline
    Test &Trial\\
    Trial &Test\\
    & Test \\
    \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Note, that I inserted \hlines for better visualisation.