# Table vertical alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

In the table below, I want to align the first three columns to the vertical center of the row. Tried many solutions but none worked. MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Triggermogelijkheden van INT0.}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\begin{tabu}  {cccX[,l,]}
\toprule
ISC01 & ISC00 & & Omschrijving \\ \midrule
  0   &   0   & \begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0.3) -- (0.3,0.3) -- (0.3,0);\draw [ultra thick] (0.3,0.0) -- (1.3,0);\draw (1.3,0) -- (1.3,0.3) -- (1.6,0.3);\end{tikzpicture} & Een laag niveau op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\ \midrule
  0   &   1   & \begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0.3) -- (0.3,0.3);\draw [ultra thick] (0.3,0.3) -- (0.3,0.0);\draw (0.3,0) -- (1.3,0);\draw [ultra thick] (1.3,0) -- (1.3,0.3);\draw (1.3,0.3) -- (1.6,0.3);\end{tikzpicture} & Een opgaande of neergaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\ \midrule
  1   &   0   & \begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0.3) -- (0.3,0.3);\draw [ultra thick] (0.3,0.3) -- (0.3,0.0);\draw (0.3,0) -- (1.3,0);\draw (1.3,0) -- (1.3,0.3);\draw (1.3,0.3) -- (1.6,0.3);\end{tikzpicture} & Een neergaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\  \midrule
  1   &   1   & \begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0.3) -- (0.3,0.3);\draw (0.3,0.3) -- (0.3,0.0);\draw (0.3,0) -- (1.3,0);\draw [ultra thick] (1.3,0) -- (1.3,0.3);\draw (1.3,0.3) -- (1.6,0.3);\end{tikzpicture} & Een opgaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: have a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells here are some examples regarding `\vcenter` and `\centering`

Answer (score 2):

this example worked for me

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>
{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|} \hline\textbf{Topic} & \textbf{Paragraph}
\\\hline
1 & This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I honestly don't know the tabu package.

Comment: It works with `tabular` but not with `tabu`.

Comment: don't use tabu! it is based on old version of `array` and since it is not maintained, it will not be adopted to changes in `array` . above proposed solution works fine!

Answer (score 2):

I would put the text into a `\parbox` that's aligned on its vertical center.

[image]

I've added some structs at the beginning and end of the parbox which you may tweak (or remove) to your liking.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\pgfkeys{%%
  /tikz/present A/.style={},
  /tikz/present B/.style={},
  /tikz/present C/.style={},
  /tikz/present D/.style={},
  /tikz/present E/.style={},
  /tikz/emph A/.code={\tikzset{/tikz/present A/.style={ultra thick}}},
  /tikz/emph B/.code={\tikzset{/tikz/present B/.style={ultra thick}}},
  /tikz/emph C/.code={\tikzset{/tikz/present C/.style={ultra thick}}},
  /tikz/emph D/.code={\tikzset{/tikz/present D/.style={ultra thick}}},
  /tikz/emph E/.code={\tikzset{/tikz/present E/.style={ultra thick}}},
  }

\newcommand\aepic[1]{%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \draw[present A] (0  ,0.3) -- (0.3,0.3);
    \draw[present B] (0.3,0.3) -- (0.3,0.0);
    \draw[present C] (0.3,  0) -- (1.3,0);
    \draw[present D] (1.3,  0) -- (1.3,0.3);
    \draw[present E] (1.3,0.3) -- (1.6,0.3);
  \end{tikzpicture} 
  }

\newcommand\mytabuparbox[1]{%%
  \parbox{3in}{\raggedright\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}#1\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Triggermogelijkheden van INT0.}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\begin{tabu}  {cccX[,l,]}
\toprule
ISC01 & ISC00 &                       & Omschrijving \\ \midrule
  0   & 0     & \aepic{emph C}        & \mytabuparbox{Een laag niveau op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt.}                  \\ \midrule
  0   & 1     & \aepic{emph B,emph D} & \mytabuparbox{Een opgaande of neergaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt.} \\ \midrule
  1   & 0     & \aepic{emph B}        & \mytabuparbox{Een neergaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt.}             \\ \midrule
  1   & 1     & \aepic{emph D}        & \mytabuparbox{Een opgaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt.}               \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Also, since your TikZ code is virtually all identical, I've created a command that presents the basic structure and added a few keys to get the desired effects.

Answer (score 2):

You must define the cell alignment of `X column` you have the options `l,c,r` for horizontal align, and `p,m,b` for vertical, to control the cell text separations you have `\tabulinesep` value; then you must define the table width to `\linewidth` and declare the size of each column and each alignment this case `{X[mc]X[mc]X[mc]X[5m]}` the column width is proportional to each number in the X column. see [tabu manual](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf), tabu is an extension of `tabularx` package, you must include it in your document.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Triggermogelijkheden van INT0.}
\tabulinesep = 5pt
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth  {X[mc]X[mc]X[mc]X[5m]}
\tabucline -
ISC01 & ISC00 & & Omschrijving \\ \tabucline -
  0   &   0   & \begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0.3) -- (0.3,0.3) -- (0.3,0);\draw [ultra thick] (0.3,0.0) -- (1.3,0);\draw (1.3,0) -- (1.3,0.3) -- (1.6,0.3);\end{tikzpicture} & Een laag niveau op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\ \tabucline -
  0   &   1   & \begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0.3) -- (0.3,0.3);\draw [ultra thick] (0.3,0.3) -- (0.3,0.0);\draw (0.3,0) -- (1.3,0);\draw [ultra thick] (1.3,0) -- (1.3,0.3);\draw (1.3,0.3) -- (1.6,0.3);\end{tikzpicture} & Een opgaande of neergaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\ \tabucline -
  1   &   0   & \begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0.3) -- (0.3,0.3);\draw [ultra thick] (0.3,0.3) -- (0.3,0.0);\draw (0.3,0) -- (1.3,0);\draw (1.3,0) -- (1.3,0.3);\draw (1.3,0.3) -- (1.6,0.3);\end{tikzpicture} & Een neergaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\  \tabucline -
  1   &   1   & \begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0.3) -- (0.3,0.3);\draw (0.3,0.3) -- (0.3,0.0);\draw (0.3,0) -- (1.3,0);\draw [ultra thick] (1.3,0) -- (1.3,0.3);\draw (1.3,0.3) -- (1.6,0.3);\end{tikzpicture} & Een opgaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\ \tabucline -
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM:**

If you want to improve to reuse the tikz code you could define a drawing with conditional parts using `\ifnum{contdition} drawing_statements \fi`, and reuse a path coordinates asingning a name using `coordinate(coordinate_name)`, so you can use the coordinate names to asign some in conditional drawings; in your example there are 3 switching objets you can control if they apear or not using values like in `\sqwave[#1][#2][#3]{}` each `#number` controls if some apears or not, in this case apears if the `#number` value is 1.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Triggermogelijkheden van INT0.}
\tabulinesep = 5pt
\def\sqwave[#1][#2][#3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=-0.25pt, shorten <=-0.25pt]
        \draw[black!30]
        (0,0.3)
            -- ++ (0.3,0) coordinate (a)
            -- ++ (0,-0.3) coordinate (b)
            -- ++ (1,0) coordinate (c)
            -- ++ (0,0.3) coordinate (d)
            -- ++ (0.3,0);
        \ifnum#1=1 \draw[line width=1.5pt] (a)--(b);\fi
        \ifnum#2=1 \draw[line width=1.5pt] (b)--(c);\fi
        \ifnum#3=1 \draw[line width=1.5pt] (c)--(d);\fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth  {X[mc]X[mc]X[mc]X[5m]}
\tabucline -
ISC01 & ISC00 & & Omschrijving \\ \tabucline -
  0   &   0   & \sqwave[0][1][0] & Een laag niveau op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\ \tabucline -
  0   &   1   & \sqwave[1][0][1] & Een opgaande of neergaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\ \tabucline -
  1   &   0   & \sqwave[1][0][0] & Een neergaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\  \tabucline -
  1   &   1   & \sqwave[0][0][1] & Een opgaande flank op de INT0-ingang genereert een interrupt. \\ \tabucline -
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```