# Prevent table from going off page, how?

Tags: tables

How can I prevent this table from going off the page please?
I need solution for both vertical overflowing and horizontal overflowing

1. For horizontal, it exceeds the page on the right side. How to limit and scale it so that it fit the page width.  See MWE 1
2. For vertical, the table does not break and continue of the next page. It just stops at the very bottom of the first page and is incomplete. See MWE 2
3. MWE 3 has both types of overflow. Basically, I want to scale the table to linewidth, and let it continue on next page.

Thank you in advance

**Here is my MWE 1 for horizontal overflowing**

```
 \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Relationship of the lesson with the ARCS model}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
\hline
\textbf{Attention}    & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.~  \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Relevance}    & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.~  \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Confidence}   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.~  \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Satisfaction} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.~  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Here is my MWE 2 for vertical overflowing**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|} 
\hline
Test 1 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra. Suspendisse maximus nunc quis arcu auctor, a auctor nunc faucibus. Quisque id lorem ut mauris imperdiet facilisis. Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat augue, nec.  \\ 
\hline
Test 2 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra. Suspendisse maximus nunc quis arcu auctor, a auctor nunc faucibus. Quisque id lorem ut mauris imperdiet facilisis. Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat augue, nec.  \\ 
\hline
Test 3 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra. Suspendisse maximus nunc quis arcu auctor, a auctor nunc faucibus. Quisque id lorem ut mauris imperdiet facilisis. Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat augue, nec.  \\ 
\hline
Test 4 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra. Suspendisse maximus nunc quis arcu auctor, a auctor nunc faucibus. Quisque id lorem ut mauris imperdiet facilisis. Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat augue, nec.  \\ 
\hline
Test 5 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra. Suspendisse maximus nunc quis arcu auctor, a auctor nunc faucibus. Quisque id lorem ut mauris imperdiet facilisis. Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat augue, nec.  \\ 
\hline
Test 6 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra. Suspendisse maximus nunc quis arcu auctor, a auctor nunc faucibus. Quisque id lorem ut mauris imperdiet facilisis. Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat augue, nec.  \\ 
\hline
Test 7 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra. Suspendisse maximus nunc quis arcu auctor, a auctor nunc faucibus. Quisque id lorem ut mauris imperdiet facilisis. Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat augue, nec.  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

MWE 3 needing horizontal scaling and flow to next page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Suspendisse maximus} & Mauris~                   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & feugiat~                  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & Mauris~                   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Suspendisse maximus} & feugiat~                  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & feugiat~                  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & Mauris~                   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{Suspendisse maximus} & \multirow{3}{*}{Mauris~}  & habitasse~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, \\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. \\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum \\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}       \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & venenatis~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & \multirow{3}{*}{feugiat~} & venenatis~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & habitasse~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & \multirow{3}{*}{Mauris~}  & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & habitasse~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~                & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~}                                                                                                                                   \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~ ~ ~            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~ ~ ~}                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~ ~ ~            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~ ~ ~}                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~ ~ ~            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~ ~ ~}                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
                                     &                           & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the text? Do you want to have a line break, in what section of the text?

Comment: When adding an example you should add enough code to make it compilable

Comment: Updated the MWE.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by "going off the page" you mean overflowing the page margin instead of adding a line break, you can fix the problem by using the `p` (Paragraph) column type that takes a width argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Relationship of the lesson with the ARCS model}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|} 
    \hline
    \textbf{Attention}    & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.~  \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Relevance}    & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.~  \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Confidence}   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.~  \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Satisfaction} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.~  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works. Thanks.  Now how do I center the Attention, Relevance etc. in the middle of the cell?

Comment: I have added another question concerning vertical overflow, can you help ?

Comment: @NadeemMuhammad: If you want your table to automatically be continued on a second page, you will need the `longtable` package.

Comment: @NadeemMuhammad it is really bad practice to edit your question to include new questions after an answer has been made that covers the original question. In the future, please create a new question for that. Apart from that leandriis is right: If you want your table to continue on another page you need a longtable. For centering you can add `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` after also having `\usepackage{array}` and then use the `P`column type instead of the `p` one

Comment: i took liberty and add picture of table generated by suggested solution.

Comment: Thanks Raven for guiding me about this malpractice.  I thought that it would be a good idea to have all three scenario in one place.  Easy for me, easy for others as well.  Thanks for the suggestion, I will give it a try.

Comment: I tested, its centering the text in the cell, but its on the top, and not the middle of the large cell.  How do I make the text centered middle position in the cell?

Comment: @NadeemMuhammad have a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells

Answer (score 3):

i would use `tabularx` table environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Relationship of the lesson with the ARCS model}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries}l|X|}
    \hline
Attention       & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.  \\
    \hline
Relevance       & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.  \\
    \hline
Confidence      & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.  \\
    \hline
Satisfaction    & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.  \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders).