# Adjusting table to linewidth and continue on next pages

Tags: tables

I need to have this table adjusted to the line width as it is exceeding the page.  I also need it to continue on the next page.  How can I do this?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Suspendisse maximus} & Mauris~                   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & feugiat~                  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & Mauris~                   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Suspendisse maximus} & feugiat~                  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & feugiat~                  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & Mauris~                   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{Suspendisse maximus} & \multirow{3}{*}{Mauris~}  & habitasse~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, \\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. \\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum \\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}       \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & venenatis~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & \multirow{3}{*}{feugiat~} & venenatis~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & habitasse~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & \multirow{3}{*}{Mauris~}  & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & habitasse~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~                & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~}                                                                                                                                   \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~ ~ ~            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~ ~ ~}                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~ ~ ~            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~ ~ ~}                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~ ~ ~            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~ ~ ~}                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
                                     &                           & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}l}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you know package `longtable`? Longtables can span pages. Can you please add an screenshot of your resulting table to your question?

Comment: Screenshot added. can you show me how to make this work please.

Answer (score 2):

To give you a starting point please have a look to the following mwe. It is only a starting point because -- for example -- you did not tell us how the table should be continued on the second page (with header on second page or footer on first page?). To work out the table is left for you ... Please see that I changed your `l` in your different tables (have a look to the subtables too!) to be something like `p{2cm}`, change the value of `2cm` to your needs.

Please see that you got some helpful advices in [your former question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480652/16550) mentioning `tabularx`. Please see that you need to use `ltablex` to use `longtable` and `tabularx` together. Please read the documentations: type for example `texdoc longtable`
in your console/terminal to get the documentation of `longtable` displayed.

Think about the table to get rid of the vertical lines and use horizontal lines minimal ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\small
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{6cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{2cm}{Suspendisse maximus} & Mauris~                   & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & feugiat~                  & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & Mauris~                   & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{2cm}{Suspendisse maximus} & feugiat~                  & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & feugiat~                  & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & Mauris~                   & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Nulla vel venenatis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pretium metus sit amet erat tristique, non mollis velit pharetra.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{9}{2cm}{Suspendisse maximus} & \multirow{3}{*}{Mauris~}  & habitasse~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{6.5cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis, \\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor. \\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum \\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}       \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & venenatis~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{6.5cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{6.5cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & \multirow{3}{*}{feugiat~} & venenatis~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{6.5cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{6.5cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & habitasse~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{6.5cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{2-4}
                                     & \multirow{3}{*}{Mauris~}  & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{6.5cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & habitasse~ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{6.5cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\cline{3-4}
                                     &                           & dictumst   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{6.5cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}          \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~                & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~}                                                                                                                                   \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~ ~ ~            & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~ ~ ~}                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~ ~ ~            & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~ ~ ~}                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
Suspendisse maximus                  & habitasse~ ~ ~            & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dignissim molestie massa, ac mattis massa varius nec. Morbi vitae ullamcorper est. Phasellus mollis tristique ipsum sed ullamcorper. Nulla vel venenatis tellus.~ ~ ~}                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
                                     &                           & \multicolumn{2}{p{7cm}|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{9cm}@{}}\begin{tabular}{@{\labelitemi\hspace{\dimexpr\labelsep+0.5\tabcolsep}}p{6.5cm}}Ut interdum, mauris vitae molestie venenatis,\\turpis turpis varius felis, eget imperdiet leo nulla laoreet tortor.\\Donec vel mi quam. Phasellus tincidunt quam in nisl elementum\\porta. Mauris a augue nisl. Proin viverra feugiat~ ~\end{tabular}\end{tabular}}  \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: first page]

and second page:

[image: second page]

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  I will give it due consideration.  It appears making complex tables in latex is quite complicated.  We really need to start from the simplest table and move on step by step.