# How to draw a side line in table

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c X | c | c | c |}
    \cline{3-5}
    &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Paired Differences} \\
    \cline{3-5}
     & & Mean &  Std. Deviation & Std. Error Mean \\
         \hline
    Pair 1 & Testing 1 and Testing 2 and Testing 3 & 4.20\% & 44.6\% & 4.54\%  \\
    \hline
      \end{tabularx}
\caption{Testing 123}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Outcome:

[image]

I cannot figure out.
If I added `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c X | c | c | c |}`
It will not be working

Comment: Try \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Pair 1} or just add it to the main column description and use \multicolumn to remove it where not wanted.

Comment: Thanks, it work!

Comment: On an completely unrelated note: with `booktabs` your table looks better: https://pastebin.com/r38axb1c. If you'd like to vertically center the cells, look into https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells.

Comment: Why do you ask the same question two times?

Comment: @Sveinung It is different pattern. I had tried `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Testing123 Testin123 Testing123 Testin123}`. following the suggestion on this page, but it came out out of width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}     \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c X |                % <---
                             *{3}{S[table-format=2.2,  % <---
                                    table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}|}} 
    \cline{3-5}
\mcc[2]{} % <---
        & \mcc[3]{Paired Differences}       \cr
    \cline{3-5}
\mcc[2]{} % <---
        & \mcc{Mean} & \mcc{Std. Deviation} & \mcc{Std. Error Mean} \cr
         \hline
Pair 1 & Testing 1 and Testing 2 and Testing 3
        & 4.20  & 44.6  & 4.54                          \cr
    \hline
      \end{tabularx}
\caption{Testing 123}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Less sophisticated version of above answer is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}     


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c X |                % <---
                             *{3}{S[table-format=2.2,  % <---
                                    table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}|}}
    \cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Paired Differences}               \cr
    \cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mean} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Std. Deviation} 
                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Std. Error Mean}  \cr
         \hline
Pair 1 & Testing 1 and Testing 2 and Testing 3
        & 4.20  & 44.6  & 4.54                                  \cr
    \hline
      \end{tabularx}
\caption{Testing 123}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

where `S` column type is defined in `siunitx` package. Details of its options and use see the package documentation, (sub)section *5.14 Tabular material*, pp 44. Short summary:

- in `tabular` preamble are defined number of columns their types:

  - `c` column type center cells contents (and it is wide as text is long)
  - `X` column type exist in `tabularx` table environment. It width is calculate by package, contents in it is set as paragraph, meaning that automatically break lines
  - vertical bars `|` define vertical lines in table. It are present in all cells which are *not* overwrite with `\multicolumn` cells.
- `\multicolumn` command merge adjacent cells into one cell (or define new column type for single cells)
- `table-format=2.2` means `<integer part>.<decimal part>` of number. Numbers in column are aligned at decimal point
- `table-space-text-post=\,\%` determine additional to horizontal space after number (reserved for small space `\,` and symbol `%`

For more information I strongly encourage you to read some introductory text about table writing. For example [Wiki book: Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) and of course in the packages documentations. They are part of your LaTeX installation (in `latex/doc` folder) or they are available on CTAN archive.

Concerning the original answer:
- package `xparse` (stored in `doc/generic` folder, as stated in its document documentation is:

> The xparse package provides a high-level interface for producing
>   document-level commands. In that way, it is intended as a replacement
>   for the LATEX 2ε \newcommand macro. However, xparse works so that the
>   interface to a function (optional arguments, stars and mandatory
>   arguments, for example) is separate from the internal implementation.
>   xparse provides a normalised input for the internal form of a
>   function, independent of the document-level argument arrangement.

so with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{...}` is defined new command which enable witting shorter code. For example:

- `O{1}` is option `1` (in our case number of columns. Is option is not used, number of columns is `1`
  . `m` is mandatory argument, which in our case is a text in the multi column cell.
- example of its uses are:

  - `\mcc{text}` is defined as equivalent to code `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{text}` (see preamble in original answer)
  - `\mcc[r]{text over three columns}` is equivalent for \multicolumn{3}{c|}{text over three columns}`

Comment: Thanks! Worked well. One question, how to cancel off the verticle line between the `Pair 1` and `Testing 1 and testing 2 and testing 3`?

Comment: @user193541, just remove `|` between `c` and `X` column type. See corrected answer.

Comment: Thanks. Hard to understand what `\mcc` doing. It is well very done.

Comment: @user193541, `mcc` is new command with optional number of spanned columns (if it bigger than 1)  for short writing `\multicolumn{<number of spanned columns>}{c|}{< text in cell>}`. Defined is by help of `xparse˙package. if answer solve your problem, you can accept it ;-).

Comment: Thanks, what does ` *{3}{S[table-format=2.2,  % <---   table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}|}} ` means?

Comment: @user193541, it defines three `S` columns' type, which enables align numbers in columns at their decimal points. For details see `siunitx` package documentation,  subsection *5.14 Tabular material*.