# How I can make picture a bit down and text up in the table?

Tags: tables, graphics

I've got such code, which gives me a table. I need to make picture a bit down and text on the same line with picture. How can I solve this problem?

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.15\linewidth}p{0.38\linewidth}p{0.38\linewidth}}
        Символ & Состояние                                                     & Описание                                                                                                                                          \\ 
        \hline\hline
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{im2}& Двигатель-генератор включен (зеленый)                         & Двигатель работает и переключатель управления генератором в положении "Включен"                                                                   \\ 
        \hline\hline
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{im3}& Двигатель-генератор выключен (белый)                          & Двигатель не работает или переключатель управления генератором в положении "Выключен" при работающем двигателе                                    \\ 
        \hline\hline
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{im4}& Стартер двигателя включен (белый квадрат с зеленой стрелкой)  & Идет запуск двигателя.                                                                                                                            \\ 
        \hline\hline
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{im5}& Неисправность генератора (оранжевый)                          & Двигатель запущен, и:переключатель управления генератором в положении "Включен"Обнаружена ошибка генератораГорит индикатор выключения генератора  \\ 
        \hline\hline
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{im6}& Данные от генератора недоступны (белый, низкая интенсивность) & Состояние генератора неизвестно                                                                                                                   \\ 
        \hline\hline
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{im7}& Оба (L1, L2 или R1,R2) стартера не работают (оранжевый)       & Если оба стартера на соответствующем двигателе выходят из строя, то появляется сообщение стартеров                                               
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to  TeX SX! You can try `\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{...}}`.

Comment: In such way the picture is going a bit down, but text in the same position. If I use it in both text and picture, there is no text transfer from one line to another

Comment: It should be used only for the graphic file, because the graphic image lies  *on* the first line. But do you want the top of the image aligned with  the first line of the next cell,  or the image centred w.r.t. the text in the next cell?

Comment: This might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells

Answer (score 1):

I would use `adjustimage` defined in the `adjustbox` package instead `includegraphics` and move images baseline ba its instruction `valign` to their top. Also instead `tabular` would rather use `tabularx` table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage[demo,   % in real document remove this option!
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}            
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \adjustboxset{width=2cm, height=2cm,
                  valign=t, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt} % settings for image appearing
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cLL}
        Символ  & Состояние     & Описание  \\
        \hline\hline
        \adjustimage{}{im2} & Двигатель-генератор включен (зеленый)                         & Двигатель работает и переключатель управления генератором в положении "Включен"                                                                   \\
        \hline\hline
        \adjustimage{}{im3} & Двигатель-генератор выключен (белый)                          & Двигатель не работает или переключатель управления генератором в положении "Выключен" при работающем двигателе                                    \\
        \hline\hline
        \adjustimage{}{im4} & Стартер двигателя включен (белый квадрат с зеленой стрелкой)  & Идет запуск двигателя.                                                                                                                            \\
        \hline\hline
        \adjustimage{}{im5} & Неисправность генератора (оранжевый)                          & Двигатель запущен, и:переключатель управления генератором в положении "Включен"Обнаружена ошибка генератораГорит индикатор выключения генератора  \\
        \hline\hline
        \adjustimage{}{im6} & Данные от генератора недоступны (белый, низкая интенсивность) & Состояние генератора неизвестно                                                                                                                   \\
        \hline\hline
        \adjustimage{}{im7} & Оба (L1, L2 или R1,R2) стартера не работают (оранжевый)       & Если оба стартера на соответствующем двигателе выходят из строя, то появляется сообщение стартеров
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*:
In table I would rather use `\midrule` defined in the `booktabs` package instead double lines produced by `\hline\hline`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way how to solve it 
just change

`\begin{tabular}{m{0.15\linewidth}m{0.38\linewidth}m{0.38\linewidth}}`