# How to vertically center align text in table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

As you can see in the picture below, I have a table that doesn't look so great and that's because am unable to figure out how to change the veritical alignment on the text in the table. For example, I want the start and the caret symbols to be vertically center aligned in the table so it looks more polished and clean.

Am using

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{array}` then use the `m{<length>}` column specification.

Comment: I've removed the `align` tag; that's specific to a particular display math environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to vertically-center the text of the cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells)

Comment: this will meet your requirement-- http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/vtable/vtable.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is vertical alignment then there is an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells) I think.

My initial answer is about horizontal position I think and does not address the question, but in case I got this wrong see below.

---

This seems too simple an answer, but can you just use

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

where the `c` replaces an `l` for the text justification for the first column. `c` means centre the text in the cell. `l` means left justify the text.

Sorry I may have missed the point, but I am guessing this might sort things out for you.

Comment: could you please post a screenshot of the output of the above code--there are two centerings-- `Left**C**Right` and `Top**C**Bottom`