# Multiple rows in Latex

Tags: multicolumn, multirow

Could anyone help me with how to create a table shown in the picture in latex? Thank you[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se. Please tell us what in particular about the table you wish to replicate.

Comment: For the interrupted horizontal lines, you can use `\cline`(For example as in `\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6}`). For the text "So That", you could use the `\multirow` command from the `multirow` package (For example as in `\multirow[b]{4}{1.7cm}{AS a \textbf{Manager} I want to}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  You've tagged this as `multirow`.  Have you looked for examples of that usage?

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, it's very easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{llp{1in}lp{1in}l|}[hvlines]
0   & Role             & Feature &      & Goal/Objective & Priority \\
US1 & \Block{4-1}{As a \\ \textbf{manager},\\ I want do} & & \Block{4-1}{so\\ that} \\
US2 \\ 
US3 \\
US4 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks, F. Pantigny, for introducing me to a new package.

Comment: doesn'work on TL2000. The '\\' are ignored: |tex / log / aux| files   http://ix.io/2EdV

Comment: @gigiair: It will work with the latest version of `nicematrix`: version 5.6 of 2020/11/08

Answer (score 1):

In a very simple way:

```
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{1in}|l|p{1in}|l|}
    \hline%
    N0  & Role             & Feature &      & Goal/Objective & Priority \\%
    \hline%
    US1 &                  &         &      &                &          \\%
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-6}%
    US2 & AS a             &         & So   &                &          \\%
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-6}%
    US3 & \textbf{Manager} &         & that &                &          \\%
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-6}%
    US4 & I want to        &         &      &                &          \\%
    \hline%
 \end{tabular}
```

Note that vertical lines in table are not recommended: they are ugly.
For horizontal lines you can use \toprule, midrule, or \bottomrule from booktabs.

[image: table verticaly centered]

Comment: Text is not centered vertically within the respective cell, most noticeably in the top row and left column. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells you can type \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} before the tabular declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using `\multirow`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{|l|p{1.75cm}|p{3cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{4cm}|l|}%
    \hline%
    N0  & Role                                                  & Feature &                          & Goal/Objective & Priority \\
    \hline%
    US1 &  \multirow[b]{4}{=}{AS a \textbf{Manager} I want to}  &         & \multirow{4}{=}{So that} &                &          \\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-6}%
    US2 &                                                       &         &                          &                &          \\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-6}%
    US3 &                                                       &         &                          &                &          \\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-6}%
    US4 &                                                       &         &                          &                &          \\
    \hline%
 \end{tabular}
 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: probably you have omit some multirow stuff  ...

Comment: @gigiair: Sorry. I unintentionally uploaded the wrong document. Thanks for pointing this out.