# Positioning text next to a picture in tabular

Tags: tables, diagrams

I'm making a list and next to each element of the list I want to put a picture of that element, I'm trying to use tabular, and with that the picture is next to the text, but I want the text to be centered in the middle, not at the bottom of the picture.
Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}

      $A_n:\ y^2-x^{n+1}=0$ &  \includegraphics[width=60mm]{images/An szing.pdf} \\
       & \\
      $D_n$ &   \includegraphics[width=60mm]{images/D_n szing.pdf}\\

    
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And heres what comes out:
[image]

Any help is appreciated, and also sorry if my question is not well put together, first time here.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

With the link indicated by José Carlos Santos, there is an answer from the author of the tabularray package. (It allowed me to see the importance of `stretch=0` and the `h` for image alignment).

[How to vertically-center the text of the cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells/611601#611601)

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=2cm,hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
colspec = {X[c,mode=math]Q[c,h]},
stretch = 0,
rowsep = 6pt,
hlines = {red5, 1pt},
vlines = {red5, 1pt},
}
A_n:\ y^2-x^{n+1}=0&\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
D_n                &\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy fix to your problem if you load `adjustbox` with optional `[export]`. Simply add `valign=c` to options of `\includegraphic` and such image will be centred.

In the code, I also redefined columns for convenience: the first to `>{$}c<{$}` so math expressions no longer required `$...$` (requires `array` package); and the second to `p{60mm}`. With the latter change, if `width` is specified as `\linewidth`, the image will gain optional width equal to its parent column, so the parameter can be change only in one place.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
        >{$}c<{$}
        p{60mm}
    }
    A_n:\ y^2-x^{n+1}=0
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{images/An szing.pdf}
    \\[10ex]
    D_n
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{images/D_n szing.pdf}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]