# How do I align things in the following tabular environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to get what's below in order in the sense of: (a) the black text on the left (xx, yy, zz) should be vertically aligned with respect to the relevant table cell on the right; (b) there is no so much space between the left column and the right column with the boxes; (c) this is a tricky one: as you can see, in the lowest set of boxes on the right, I am trying to align D and E with B and C, but for some reason, the tikz picture gets "cropped".

I should mention I am using tabularray after finding the following answer: [How to vertically-center the text of the cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells/611601#611601)

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
colspec = {X[l,m]X[l,m]},
rowsep = 0pt,
colsep = 0pt
}

zz: & something \\

yy: & \begin{tikzpicture}[cc/.style={fill=blue!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cyellow/.style={align=center,fill=yellow!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cgreen/.style={fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},corange/.style={fill=orange!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm}]

\path  (0,0) node[cc] (A) {A} (2.3,0) node[cc] (B) {B} (4.6,0) node[cc] (C) {C};
\draw[->] (A)--(B);
\draw[->] (B)--(C);

\end{tikzpicture} \\

xx & \begin{tikzpicture}[cc/.style={fill=blue!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cyellow/.style={align=center,fill=yellow!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cgreen/.style={align=center,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},corange/.style={align=center,fill=orange!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm}]


\path (2.3,0) node[cyellow] (AA) {D} (4.6,0) node[cgreen] (BB) {E};
\draw[->] (AA)--(BB);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `X` stretches the column to fill a horizontal space. If you don't want that don't use it. You can use `baseline=(A.base)` or `baseline=(AA.base)` to vertically align the TikZ pictures correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this? I used a normal `tabular` environment, put the `tikzpicture`s in math mode and `\vcenter`ed them.
[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    zz: & something\\
    yy: & $\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),cc/.style={fill=blue!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cyellow/.style={align=center,fill=yellow!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cgreen/.style={fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},corange/.style={fill=orange!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm}]
        \path  (0,0) node[cc] (A) {A} (2.3,0) node[cc] (B) {B} (4.6,0) node[cc] (C) {C};
        \draw[->] (A)--(B);
        \draw[->] (B)--(C);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}$ \\
    xx: & $\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[cc/.style={fill=blue!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cyellow/.style={align=center,fill=yellow!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},cgreen/.style={align=center,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},corange/.style={align=center,fill=orange!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm}]
        \path (2.3,0) node[cyellow] (AA) {D} (4.6,0) node[cgreen] (BB) {E};
        \draw[->] (AA)--(BB);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, it is almost right, but the D and E need to be under the B and the C... I put the coordinates correctly, but it seems like tikz pushes it away. I suppose I could put a hidden node somehow at (0,0) and that should fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I misread this part. I'd just insert a `\hspace{23mm}` (box width + arrow length) before `\vcenter` which gives the correct output, but this is quite improper and will not work as soon as your box becomes wider than its minimum width.

Comment: thanks! my trick with a hidden (0,0) node worked!

Answer (score 5):

(a) Set the baseline of tikz pictures.
(b) Use `Q` column type instead of `X`.
(c) Draw an invisible node below A to align B with D and C with E.

I have increased the box height just to demonstrate.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {Q[l,m] Q[l,m]},
            rowsep = 0pt,
            colsep = 0pt
        }
        
        zz: & something \\
        
        yy: & \begin{tikzpicture}[
            cc/.style={fill=blue!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm,minimum height=10mm},
            cyellow/.style={align=center,fill=yellow!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},
            cgreen/.style={fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},
            corange/.style={fill=orange!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},
            baseline={(A.base)}
        ]
            
            \path  (0,0) node[cc] (A) {A} (2.3,0) node[cc] (B) {B} (4.6,0) node[cc] (C) {C};
            \draw[->] (A)--(B);
            \draw[->] (B)--(C);
            %\path node (yy) [left=of A, inner sep=0pt, rectangle, draw] {yy};
            
        \end{tikzpicture} \\
        
        xx & \begin{tikzpicture}[
            cc/.style={fill=blue!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},
            cyellow/.style={align=center,fill=yellow!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm,minimum height=10mm},
            cgreen/.style={align=center,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},
            corange/.style={align=center,fill=orange!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick,inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},
            invisible/.style={inner sep=4,outer sep=0,minimum width=18mm},
            baseline={(AA.base)}
        ]
            
            
            \path (0,0) node[invisible] {} (2.3,0) node[cyellow] (AA) {D} (4.6,0) node[cgreen] (BB) {E};
            \draw[->] (AA)--(BB);
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- used `arrows.meta˛` chains`and`positioning` Ti*k*Z libraries
- common tikz style definition
- short code ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains, 
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{        
node distance = 0mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {fill=#1!20, rounded corners=2pt, anchor=base,
                 inner ysep=4mm, inner xsep=0mm, minimum width=18mm, 
                 on chain},
     N/.default = blue,
every edge/.append style = {-Straight Barb,}
        }
        
       
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l,m] Q[r,m, wd=64mm]},
              colsep = 1mm, rowsep  = 0pt}

zz: &   \SetCell{l} something \\
yy: &   \tikz[baseline=1pt]
        {\node[N] (a)   {A}; 
         \node[N] (b)   {B}; 
         \node[N] (c)   {C};
         \draw  (a) edge (b)    (b) edge (c);
         }  \\
xx: &    \tikz[baseline=1pt]
        {\node[N=yellow] (a)   {D};
         \node[N=green]  (b)   {E};
         \draw  (a) edge (b);
         }
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
or a bit shorter code by use of the `join` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
node distance = 0mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {fill=#1!20, rounded corners=2pt, anchor=base,
                 inner ysep=4mm, inner xsep=0mm, minimum width=18mm,
                 on chain},
     N/.default = blue,
every join/.style = {-Straight Barb}    % <---
        }


\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l,m] Q[r,m, wd=64mm]},
              colsep = 1mm, rowsep  = 0pt}

zz: &   \SetCell{l} something \\
yy: &   \tikz[baseline=1pt]
        {\node[N] (a)   {A};
         \node[N, join] {B};  % <---
         \node[N, join] {C};  % <---
         }  \\
xx: &    \tikz[baseline=1pt]
        {\node[N=yellow]        {D};
         \node[N=green, join]   {E};    % <---
         }
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

In both case you get the same result:

[image]

**Addendum:**
Using @Qrrbrbirlbel answer on my [question[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678147/chain-of-nodes-connected-by-join-macro-in-table-cell) the possible solution using `graphs` library can be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                graphs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\tikzset{
     N/.style = {fill=#1!20, rounded corners=2pt, alias=N,
                 inner ysep=4mm, inner xsep=0mm, outer sep=0pt,
                 minimum width=18mm},
   N/.default = blue,
        }
\tikzgraphsset{
    branch right sep=5mm,
    every graph/.append style = {path, ->, /tikz/>=Straight Barb}}

\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[r] Q[r,wd=64mm]},
              colsep = 1mm, rowsep  = 0pt}
zz: &   \SetCell{l} something \\
yy: &   \tikz[baseline=(N.base)]    \graph{A[N],    B[N],   C[N]};  \\
xx: &   \tikz[baseline=(N.base)]    \graph{D[N=yellow], E[N=green]};
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Compilation result is almost the same as before.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's probably better if you split `tikzpicture` into separate rows. Then you will have more flexibility to manipulate rows. I added baseline with slight shift to centre rows.

The reason you have such large space is because you define columns as `X`-type, which causes environment to create columns of the equal size. Because `tikz` creates a wide image, the left column mirrors that width, hence you get huge space. Simply change columns to `Q[]`.

For the last issue, set alignment to right with exception to the first row.

I also slightly changed your code. I added a global style `ccgeneric` and then inherited the other styles based on that. This style takes a parameter: colour. It makes the code more readable, less cluttered and easier to manipulate if you need to make changes.

EDIT. The code corrected to add missing arrow tips.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  baseline={([yshift=-2pt]current bounding box)},
  every edge/.style={draw, ->},
  ccgeneral/.style={
    fill=#1,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    thick,
    inner sep=4,
    outer sep=0,
    minimum width=18mm,
  },
  cc/.style={ccgeneral=blue!20},
  cyellow/.style={ccgeneral=yellow!20},
  cgreen/.style={ccgeneral=green!20},
  corange/.style={ccgeneral=orange!20},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {Q[l,m]Q[r,m]},
    rowsep = 0pt,
    colsep = 3pt,
    row{1} = {l},
  }
  zz: & something \\
  yy: & \begin{tikzpicture}
          \path (0,0) node[cc] (A) {A} (2.3,0) node[cc] (B) {B} (4.6,0) node[cc] (C) {C};
          \draw (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C);
        \end{tikzpicture} \\
  xx: & \begin{tikzpicture}
          \path (2.3,0) node[cyellow] (D) {D} (4.6,0) node[cgreen] (E) {E};
          \draw (D) edge (E);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (and Tikz for the arrows).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Fill}{m}{\Block[fill=#1,rounded-corners]{}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{rw{c}{2cm}cw{c}{2cm}cw{c}{2cm}}[cell-space-limits=3mm]
   xx: & something \\
   yy: & \Fill{blue!15} A && \Fill{blue!15} B && \Fill{blue!15} C  \\
   xx: &   && \Fill{yellow!15} D && \Fill{green!15} E \\
\CodeAfter
   \begin{tikzpicture} [->]
   \draw (2.5-|3) -- (2.5-|4) ;
   \draw (2.5-|5) -- (2.5-|6) ;
   \draw (3.5-|5) -- (3.5-|6) ;
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix` you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]