# Chain of nodes connected by join macro in table cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-chains, join

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains, 
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{        
node distance = 0mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {fill=#1!20, name=N,
                 inner ysep=4mm, inner xsep=0mm, minimum width=22mm, 
                 on chain, join=by -Straight Barb}
        }
                   
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l,m] X[l,m]}}
DE  &   \tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{\node[N=red]   {D};    \node[N=blue]  {E};}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, result is wrong. What generate the first arrow? Do I have some error in MWE or do I miss something? Do anyone know workaround?

**Edit:**
The same result is obtained at `tabularx` table too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\UseTblrLibrary{count}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
node distance = 0mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {fill=#1!20, name=N,
                 inner ysep=4mm, inner xsep=0mm, minimum width=22mm,
                 on chain,join=by -Straight Barb}
        }

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
DE  &   \tikz[baseline=(N.base), on chain,join=by -Straight Barb]{\node[N=red]   {D};    \node[N=blue]  {E};}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't start the chain outside of your diagram. `tblr` typesets its content more than once (for measurement) and that makes TikZ thinK a previus node already exists (because it does in another picture). Put `\pgfpictureid\ \tikzchaincount` inside your node and see id 4 and 7 for “D” and 8 for “E” instead of id 1, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `tblr` typesets its content apparently at least three times (for measurement) before its actually put on the page.
2. The chain starts outside of your TikZ picture, so all those 4×2 nodes are considered part of one and the same chain.
3. PGF/TikZ doesn't really check whether a referenced node is part of the same picture.

The “D” node you finally see on the page isn't placed at `(0, 0)` either, it is placed `right` of the last `N` node of the previous picture.

Take a look at the following example. `tblr` is basically doing the same, four times the same diagram:

```
\tikzset{
node distance = 0mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {fill=#1!20, name=N,
                 inner ysep=4mm, inner xsep=0mm, minimum width=22mm, 
                 on chain, join=by -Straight Barb}
        }
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={
  execute at end picture={
    \node[circle, draw, label=$O$] at (0,0) {};
    \draw[help lines] (-1.25,0|-N.south west) grid (N.north east);}}}

\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[N=red]{D \pgfpictureid\ \tikzchaincount};
  \node[N=blue]{E \pgfpictureid\ \tikzchaincount};}

\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[N=red]{D \pgfpictureid\ \tikzchaincount};
  \node[N=blue]{E \pgfpictureid\ \tikzchaincount};}

\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[N=red]{D \pgfpictureid\ \tikzchaincount};
  \node[N=blue]{E \pgfpictureid\ \tikzchaincount};}

\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[N=red]{D \pgfpictureid\ \tikzchaincount};
  \node[N=blue]{E \pgfpictureid\ \tikzchaincount};}

\tikz % this picture doesn't have a node N but it still finds it.
  \draw foreach \ang in {0, 15, ..., 359} { (N.\ang) -- ++(\ang:5pt)};
```

This gives:
[image]

I've added the origin and a grid to all diagrams so that you can see more clearly what's actually happening.

The manual states for `start chain`:

> This key should, but need not, be given as an option to a scope enclosing all nodes of the chain. Typically, this will be a `scope` or the whole `tikzpicture`, but it might just be a path on which all nodes of the chain are found. If no *chain name* is given, the default value `chain` will be used instead.

which is not really clear but gives a hint that it maybe should only used on a per pictures basis. Though, it surely didn't forsee a picture being typeset four times.

Anyway, I'd recommend putting `start chain` at the `\tikz` picture or at least in the `tblr` cell. A chain between pictures doesn't really make sense anyway.

I've added a `reset chain` key that resets the given chain (or the active chain if no value is given), which we could add to `every picture` but I wouldn't use it. (It's also missing a check whether the given chain even exists.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  reset chain/.code=%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname tikz@lib@chain@count@#1\endcsname{0},
  reset chain/.default=\tikz@lib@current@chain}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
node distance = 0mm and 5mm,
%  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {fill=#1!20, name=N,
                 inner ysep=4mm, inner xsep=0mm, minimum width=22mm, 
                 on chain, join=by -Straight Barb}
        }
 
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l,m] X[l,m]}}
DE & \tikz[start chain=going right, baseline=(N.base)]{
       \node[N=red] {D}; \node[N=blue] {E};}
\end{tblr}

\hrule

\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l,m] X[l,m]}}
DE & \tikzset{start chain=going right}
       \tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{\node[N=red] {D}; \node[N=blue] {E};}
\end{tblr}

\hrule

\tikzset{start chain=going right, every picture/.append style=reset chain}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l,m] X[l,m]}}
DE & \tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{\node[N=red] {D}; \node[N=blue] {E};}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

You could also use the `graphs` library were you also can kind of set up the placement and connection strategy beforehand. (Though, I would specify this as part of the `\tikz` or `\graph` instead of global.)

Since the nodes `D` and `E` are not connected by `--` or similar, these are considered sibling and thus `branch right sep` is used not `grow right sep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  N/.style={
    fill=#1!20, inner ysep=4mm, inner xsep=0mm, minimum width=22mm, alias=N}}
\tikzgraphsset{branch right sep=5mm,
               every graph/.append style={path, ->, /tikz/>=Straight Barb}}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l,m] X[l,m]}}
DE  & \tikz[baseline=(N.base)]\graph{D[N=red], E[N=blue]};
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also do `every picture/.append style={start chain = going right}` outside the `tblr` which would do the same as using `start chain` at the picture itself.

Comment: For now only +1, for acception I will wait for while. Before it I first need from answer extract the  MWE and separately also explanation, both for my barn of attractive solutions (for future use).