# Why doesn't centered paragraph work inside table with tex4ht?

Tags: tables, arrays, tex4ht

I am using the solution given in [How to vertically-center the text of the cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells)  by Jimi Oke, which works well for me:

> If you also want to align all the cell contents toward the center in
> a horizontal sense

```
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{4cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{4cm} }
   ... & ... \\end{tabular}
```

In pdf, it comes out as expected. But when compiled to html using tex4ht, the columns are not centered. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2.5in}| >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1in}|>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2.5in}|  }\hline
Original ode in $x,y$ coordinates & Canonical coordinates transformation & ODE in canonical coordinates\\\hline 
$y'=\frac{y}{x}+x$ &
&
$S'=R$\\
text
&
{$\!\begin{aligned}
x& \to R\\
y& \to RS 
\end{aligned} 
$}
&
text\\\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Compiled to pdf using lualatex on TL 2022 gives

[image]

Compiled to html using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug main.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

gives

[image]

Which is not centered. I know I can use `c` for column centering and that works in tex4ht, but I needed to use the solution given in the above question for same reasons given there, which is

> How is it possible to vertically-center the text of the cells?

question is: Is it possible to make the output centered in HTML using same latex code?

The raw HTML generated by tex4ht is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='main.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<div class='center'>
<!-- l. 60 --><p class='noindent'>
</p>
<div class='tabular'> <table class='tabular' id='TBL-1'><colgroup id='TBL-1-1g'><col id='TBL-1-1' /></colgroup><colgroup id='TBL-1-2g'><col id='TBL-1-2' /></colgroup><colgroup id='TBL-1-3g'><col id='TBL-1-3' /></colgroup><tr class='hline'><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr id='TBL-1-1-' style='vertical-align:baseline;'><td class='td11' id='TBL-1-1-1' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'> <!-- l. 62 --><p class='noindent'>Original ode in \(x,y\) coordinates           </p></td>
                                        <td class='td11' id='TBL-1-1-2' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'> <!-- l. 62 --><p class='noindent'>Canonical 
coordinates 
transformation </p></td>
                                                          <td class='td11' id='TBL-1-1-3' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'> <!-- l. 62 --><p class='noindent'>ODE in canonical coordinates        </p></td>
</tr><tr class='hline'><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr id='TBL-1-2-' style='vertical-align:baseline;'><td class='td11' id='TBL-1-2-1' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'> <!-- l. 63 --><p class='noindent'>\(y'=\frac {y}{x}+x\)                               </p></td>
<td class='td11' id='TBL-1-2-2' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'> <!-- l. 64 --><p class='noindent'>             </p></td>
<td class='td11' id='TBL-1-2-3' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'> <!-- l. 65 --><p class='noindent'>\(S'=R\)                              </p></td>
</tr><tr id='TBL-1-3-' style='vertical-align:baseline;'><td class='td11' id='TBL-1-3-1' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'> <!-- l. 66 --><p class='noindent'>text                                           </p></td>
<td class='td11' id='TBL-1-3-2' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'> <!-- l. 68 --><p class='noindent'>\(\!\begin {aligned} x&amp; \to R\\ y&amp; \to RS \end {aligned} \)             </p></td>
<td class='td11' id='TBL-1-3-3' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'> <!-- l. 74 --><p class='noindent'>text                                          </p></td>
</tr><tr class='hline'><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>                                                         </div></div>
 
</body> 
</html>
```

TL 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your document a bit:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\centercell{\centering\arraybackslash}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centercell} m}
\begin{document} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| C{2.5in}| C{1in}| C{2.5in}|  }\hline
Original ode in $x,y$ coordinates & Canonical coordinates transformation & ODE in canonical coordinates\\\hline 
$y'=\frac{y}{x}+x$ &
&
$S'=R$\\
text
&
{$\!\begin{aligned}
x& \to R\\
y& \to RS 
\end{aligned} 
$}
&
text\\\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I've declared a new command, `\centercell`, and `C` column type:

```
\newcommand\centercell{\centering\arraybackslash}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centercell} m}
```

Thanks to this, you can declare the table in a much simpler way:

```
 \begin{tabular}{| C{2.5in}| C{1in}| C{2.5in}|  }\hline
```

Edit:

You can also try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}


\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter
\Configure{halignTD} {}{}
   {m}{\HCode{ style="white-space:wrap; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"}\Protect\a:HColWidth}
   {}

  \Configure{HColWidth}
     {\ifnum\HRow=1% output CSS only on the first row, to prevent duplication
      \tmp:dim=\HColWidth \divide\tmp:dim by \f@size\relax
      \Css{\#TBL-\TableNo\space td:nth-child(\HCol)% CSS selects ID of the current table column
          {width: \strip@pt\tmp:dim em;}}
     \fi}


\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It declares columns with the `m` specifier to be aligned to the center, and also saves the column width. This is the result:

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

You can then redefine `\centercell` command in TeX4ht to insert CSS instructions for the alignment change:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\renewcommand\centercell{%
\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-\HCol, \#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-\HCol p{text-align: center !important;}}%
\centering\arraybackslash}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The important bit is this:

```
 \Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-\HCol, \#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-\HCol p{text-align: center !important;}}%
```

With `\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-\HCol` you get unique ID of each table cell, and then you can define the alignment. We need to use `!important`, because all table cells have alignment set already.

This is the result:

[image]