# Center horizontally and vertically text in table with figures

Tags: tables, floats, center

I would like to have a table with figures in some columns and text in others. But I need the text to be both vertically and horizontally centered.

Moreover, since I am using a double column documentclass (revtex) I need the table to fill the whole page (both columns).

I have followed the suggestions in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells) but they have been useless for me

```
\documentclass[aps, prd, twocolumn, floats, floatfix, superscriptaddress, nofootinbib]{revtex4}

\usepackage{graphicx, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash\vspace{0pt}}m{0.5\linewidth}|c|}
        \hline
    Text 1 & \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image} \\
        \hline
    Text 2 & \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
        \caption{My table of figures}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the `valign=c` option from `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`