# Vertical alignment with nested tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, nesting

It's almost embarrassing to ask: How can I vertically align the contents of one column to the top beside a second column holding nested tables. Please have a look at the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
  \textbf{top/center} & \textbf{top/left} \\
  \midrule
  foo &
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
  \end{tabular} \\
  \midrule
  bar &
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
  \end{tabular} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In this example, "foo" and "bar" should be aligned to the top vertically and to the center horizontally. The nested tables should be aligned top left.

The contents of the tables are filled dynamically. Thus, I cannot apply tricks like using `\raisebox` or something (or at least I don't know how to apply such tricks dynamically in my case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[t]` option on any `tabular` to top align it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cl}
  \textbf{top/center} & \textbf{top/left} \\
  \midrule
  foo &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
  \end{tabular} \\
  \midrule
  bar &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
    bla & blub \\
  \end{tabular} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like I said, really embarrassing! ;) Thanks for your answer. That did the trick. But I find it somewhat surprising: I set the vertical alignment of the tables in the right column, which affects the alignment of "foo" and "bar" outside of these tables in the left column... oO

Comment: look at this previous questions [problem-with-table-vertical-alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6355/1952), [how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/). May be they help you to understand it. You can also look at `Related` questions on the right.