# Vertical alignment with array package when the line width is fixed

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I created a post earlier on the same topic ([Vertical alignment in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94716/vertical-alignment-in-tables)). I got an answer but it triggered another question.

Below the solution that has been provided. I would expect vertical centering but the text goes on top of each cell. Playing with `p`, `m`, and `b` to align vertically doesn't seem to work here. I have probably missed something...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |m{2cm}|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|@{}l@{}}
   \hline
     x &
     x &
     x &\\[5mm]
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As seen in the second row, the `m` column type is giving vertical centering of the cells, however the extra space from `\\[..]` is added *afterwards* so if your entries are only one line `b` and `p` are the same thing (and `m` isn't very different). As I noted in a comment on the previous answer, because `m` cells typically have large depth, you typically need to use a large value in the optional argument of `\\[]` before increasing the depth of the strut makes any difference. Or better try to avoid using the optional argument of `\\` in tables.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. So `\\[..]` is added afterwards and therefore `m` doesn't take the full height into account. Is that correct ? Is there another way to specify the height that would be considered by the `m` ?

Comment: If you don't use `\\[]` and do use `\arraystretch` the strut is enlarged for all rows and in `p/m/t` columns the first column gets a strut with the height and the last row gets a strut with the depth, but often simpler is just in any cell of the row use `\vspace*{2cm}`  before  and/or after the main text of the entry, that has a more direct effect and the space probably increases in a way that is more predictable