# vertically align text in table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Probably a straightforward problem. Why is the final column not center aligned vertically?

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
      \caption{Data Units, Sources, and Dates}

    \begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} |}

    \hline

    {\bf Variable} & {\bf Dates} & {\bf Units} & {\bf Source}  \\[2ex] \hline
    {\bf Nominal Physical Capital Stock} & 1950-1990 & Billions  US\$ & Nehru and Dhareshwar (1993) \\[0ex] \hline
    {\bf Total Population} & 1950-1990 & Billions & Nehru and Dhareshwar (1993) \\[0ex] \hline
    {\bf Nominal GDP} & 1950-1990 & Billions  US\$ & PWT \\[5ex] \hline
    {\bf Real GDP per capita} & 1950-1990 & 2005 US\$ per capita & PWT \\[5ex] \hline

  \end{tabular}

  \label{tabular:UKJPNdata}
  \end{center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Regarding your use of `\bf`, please see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT) Also, in terms of horizontal alignment, see [Should I use `\center` or `\centering` for figures and tables?](http://goo.gl/eePVj)

Comment: In this case the issue is with the asker's *specific* question; for the general question see [tables - Vertical alignment in tabular cells with variable height - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height)

Answer (score 22):

Since the use of `\\[<len>]` is the cause of the problem, here is a slightly different (more suggestive) solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Data Units, Sources, and Dates}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Spread rows out...
  \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\bfseries}m{1in} >{\centering}m{1in} >{\centering}m{1in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}}
    \toprule
    Variable & \textbf{Dates} & \textbf{Units} & \textbf{Source} \\
    \midrule
    Nominal Physical Capital Stock & 1950-1990 & Billions  US\$ & Nehru and Dhareshwar (1993) \\
    Total Population & 1950-1990 & Billions & Nehru and Dhareshwar (1993) \\
    Nominal GDP & 1950-1990 & Billions  US\$ & PWT \\
    Real GDP per capita & 1950-1990 & 2005 US\$ per capita & PWT \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It's best to [be consistent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764). As such, updating `\arraystretch` spreads the rows out evenly. I've also taken the liberty of using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)'s suggestions (limiting horizontal rules and *never* using vertical rules). The presentation looks cleaner and more professional.

Answer (score 10):

If you need the variable spacing from row to row, then add an extra column to hold the line spacing commands:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Data Units, Sources, and Dates}
    \begin{tabular}{| *4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}|} @{}m{0pt}@{}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Dates} & \textbf{Units} &
    \textbf{Source}  &\\[2ex] 
    \hline
    \textbf{Nominal Physical Capital Stock} & 1950-1990 & Billions
    US\$ & Nehru and Dhareshwar (1993) &\\[0ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Total Population} & 1950-1990 & Billions & Nehru and
    Dhareshwar (1993) &\\[0ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Nominal GDP} & 1950-1990 & Billions  US\$ & PWT &\\[5ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Real GDP per capita} & 1950-1990 & 2005 US\$ per capita &
    PWT &\\[5ex]
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tabular:UKJPNdata}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You can visualise why this is helping by placing a `\vrule` at the end of each final cell:

[image: Visualation example]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\myrule}{\vrule width 3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Data Units, Sources, and Dates}
    \begin{tabular}{| *4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}|}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Dates} & \textbf{Units} &
    \textbf{Source}  \myrule\\[2ex] 
    \hline
    \textbf{Nominal Physical Capital Stock} & 1950-1990 & Billions
    US\$ & Nehru and Dhareshwar (1993) \myrule\\[0ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Total Population} & 1950-1990 & Billions & Nehru and
    Dhareshwar (1993) \myrule\\[0ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Nominal GDP} & 1950-1990 & Billions  US\$ & PWT \myrule\\[5ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Real GDP per capita} & 1950-1990 & 2005 US\$ per capita &
    PWT \myrule\\[5ex]
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tabular:UKJPNdata}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Data Units, Sources, and Dates}
    \begin{tabular}{| *4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}|} @{}m{0pt}@{}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Dates} & \textbf{Units} &
    \textbf{Source}  &\myrule\\[2ex] 
    \hline
    \textbf{Nominal Physical Capital Stock} & 1950-1990 & Billions
    US\$ & Nehru and Dhareshwar (1993) &\myrule\\[0ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Total Population} & 1950-1990 & Billions & Nehru and
    Dhareshwar (1993) &\myrule\\[0ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Nominal GDP} & 1950-1990 & Billions  US\$ & PWT &\myrule\\[5ex]
    \hline
    \textbf{Real GDP per capita} & 1950-1990 & 2005 US\$ per capita &
    PWT &\myrule\\[5ex]
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tabular:UKJPNdata}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

From this you can see that the extra depth being added by at the end of lines is on the final line of the cell's paragraph.

This solution is a variation of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94717/15925 by David Carlisle; in particular a different format for the last column is given, as the other solution adding an `l` column happens not to work in this case.

Answer (score 7):

`\\[...]` is essentially `\vspace{...}\\` so that using it will add a vertical space to the last cell. A simple (but not decent) solution utilizing `calc` package is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
      \caption{Data Units, Sources, and Dates}

    \begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} |}

    \hline

    \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Dates} & \textbf{Units} & \textbf{Source}  \parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{2ex+\baselineskip}}\\ \hline
    \textbf{Nominal Physical Capital Stock} & 1950-1990 & Billions  US\$ & Nehru and Dhareshwar (1993) \\[0ex] \hline
    \textbf{Total Population} & 1950-1990 & Billions & Nehru and Dhareshwar (1993) \\[0ex] \hline
    \textbf{Nominal GDP} & 1950-1990 & Billions  US\$ & PWT \parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{5ex+\baselineskip}}\\ \hline
    \textbf{Real GDP per capita} & 1950-1990 & 2005 US\$ per capita & PWT \parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{5ex+\baselineskip}}\\ \hline

  \end{tabular}

  \label{tabular:UKJPNdata}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Don't use `{\bf text}`, use `\textbf{text}` instead. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/27635

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thanks for reminding me, those follow from OP's code :)