# Table problem: linebreaks within cells that are vertically centered AND table spanning multiple pages

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, line-breaking, longtable

After having spent a while optimizing my first table to look acceptable, I ran into a problem when I needed the same thing again, but with the table also covering multiple pages. I found out about `\longtable`, but I can't use it as it is incompatible with my other requirements as far as I can tell.
The problem with looking up answers is that I get solutions for each single problem, but I can't combine them to cover all my requirements.

required:

- uses LuaLaTex (I have to use Times New Roman)
- the table can stretch over multiple pages
- line breaks within table cells
- vertical centering of the text in each cell
- the different rows of the table have to be
  distinguishable (you need to be able to tell which table-row a word belogs
  to, even if it is in a cell with multiple lines)
- a label to be able to reference the table
- compatibility with `\begin{landscape} \end{landscape}`

things that I would highly appreciate, but that I could bear to live without if not possible otherwise:

- automatic line breaking (setting `\linebreak` manually instead)
- self-adjusting column widths
- individual setting of the horizontal alignments for each column (one column left-justified, the other centered,...)
- no warnings about underfull `\hbox`-es

In the code example below I go through the evolution of my tables, to show you some of the problems I ran into and how I solved them. I found a solution I was very happy with, but it is incompatible with `\longtable`. This nullifies all the advances I have made in terms of linebreaks within cells, vertical centering and generally producing a respectable table.

Thank you so much for your answers in advance!

Here is the code example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

% preamble


% general: margins, font, spacing

    \usepackage[twoside,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=1.25cm]{geometry}

    \usepackage{fontspec} % for times new roman
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

    \usepackage{setspace} % for 1.5 line spacing



% references to papers, figures, tables, ...

%    \usepackage[style=IEEE,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%    \addbibresource{library.bib}

    \usepackage{refstyle} % for figure references

    \usepackage{tabulary} % for easier handling of multiline entries in tables
    \usepackage{array,booktabs} % http://ctan.org/pkg/

    \usepackage{longtable} % for multi-page tables

    \usepackage{lscape} % for horizontal tables



\begin{document}
\begin{onehalfspace} % line spacing


The following table is pretty bad. One entry/row is hard to distinguish from the other. Also, it produces four warnings for underfull hboxes. Everything is aligned to the left, which is not good, but there might be a solution for this which I didn't bother to look up due to the other problems.

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{p{7.5cm}p{2cm}p{3cm}}
    \hline
    \textbf{word} & \textbf{word} & \textbf{some text} \\ \hline
    some even longer text, it \linebreak starts to get uncomfortable & some \linebreak more text & word \\
    some text that is so long that it will have \linebreak to cover multiple lines no matter what & some \linebreak text & word \\
    %\label{table:thefirstfailedattempt}
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
\bigskip


The following example is better, at least it doesn't generate warnings, decides where to include line breaks within cells and self-adjusts the width of each column. Moreover, it is easy to define the alignment for each column separately, which is something I appreciate. But the vertical centering is missing. This is not acceptable to me.

\medskip

\begin{tabulary}{14cm}{CCC} % good except for missing vertical centering
    \hline
    \textbf{word} & \textbf{word} & \textbf{some text} \\ \hline
    some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable & some more text & word \\
    some text that is so long that it will have to cover multiple lines no matter what & some text & word \\
    %\label{table:thesecondfailedattempt}
\end{tabulary}

\bigskip
\bigskip


With this solution (Table\,\ref{table:solutionfound}) I was very happy. Distinguishable rows, vertical alignment, table-label and a nice format as the cherry on top. This is what I was looking for.
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127050/vertically-align-text-in-table-in-latex

\medskip

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\caption{Data Units, Sources, and Dates}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Spread rows out...
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{7.5cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{word} & \textbf{word} & \textbf{some text} \\
    \midrule
    some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable & some more text & word \\
    some text that is so long that it will have \linebreak to cover multiple lines no matter what & some text & word \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption[The table I was happy with]{\textbf{The table I was happy with.} Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table.
    \label{table:solutionfound}}
\end{table}

\bigskip
\bigskip


But then I reached the next table (Table\,\ref{table:thetablethatistoolong}), which is quite the monster. I had to switch to landscape to fit all the columns in, but I quickly found a solution that worked. However, it is too long and stretches over multiple pages. By looking up other stackexchange answers I found out that longtable is the solution for this. But my previous solution is not compatible with longtable, which nullifies all the advances I have made in terms of linebreaks within cells, vertical centering and generally producing a respectable table.
I could split this table into three separate tables (defined by the second column), but the third table (second column is 'bar') would still be too long for one page.
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp] % doesn't work with longtable
    \centering
    %\caption{Data Units, Sources, and Dates}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Spread rows out...
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering}m{5cm} >{\centering}m{3cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{some ID} & \textbf{a property} & \textbf{another column} & \textbf{column containing much text} & \textbf{more text} & \textbf{further specification of foo} & \textbf{further specification of bar} & \textbf{final comment} \\
    \midrule
B01  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some middle-length text  \\
B02  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B04  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B05  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B06  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B08  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text with a bit more length  \\
B10  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B11  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  word  &    &  word  \\
B12  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B13  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B15  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B16  &  foo  &  word  &  some text that is so long that it will have to cover multiple lines no matter what  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B17  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B18  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B19  &  foo  &  word  &  some text that is so long that it will have to cover multiple lines no matter what  &  word  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B21  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B23  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B25  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B27  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B29  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B30  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B32  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B34  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &    &  word  \\
B35  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B39  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B41  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B42  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  word  &    &  word  \\
B45  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B04  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &  some text  &  some text  \\
B14  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &  word  &  some text  \\
B20  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  some text  &  some text  &  word  \\
B24  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  some text  \\
B26  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  \\
B28  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  some text  &  word  &  word  \\
B31  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  word  &  some text  &  word  \\
B33  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  word  \\
B40  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  some text  &  some text  &  word  \\
B44  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  \\
B46  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &  word  &  word  \\
B48  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  \\
D01  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  \\
D05  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  infiltrated  \\
D09  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  infiltrated  \\
D22  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  \\
D31  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  \\
D02  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D03  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D04  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D06  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D07  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  word  &  some text  \\
D08  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D10  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D11  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D12  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &    &  word  &  some text  \\
D13  &  bar  &  word  &  some text that is so long that it will have to cover multiple lines no matter what  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D14  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D15  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D16  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D17  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D18  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D19  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D20  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  word  &  infiltrated  \\
D21  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D23  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D24  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D25  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D26  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D27  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D28  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D29  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D32  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D33  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D34  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D35  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D38  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D39  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D40  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D42  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D43  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length   &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D44  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D45  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D46  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption[This table is too long]{\textbf{This table is too long, you won't even see this.} Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table.
    \label{table:thetablethatistoolong}}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{onehalfspace} % line spacing
\end{document}
```

Comment: the setting of table cells in `longtable` is identical to that of `tabular` (it uses the same code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what you did with `longtable` but presumably you did something wrong, if I switch in `longtable` it seems to work OK.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

% preamble


% general: margins, font, spacing

    \usepackage[twoside,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=1.25cm]{geometry}

    \usepackage{fontspec} % for times new roman
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

    \usepackage{setspace} % for 1.5 line spacing



% references to papers, figures, tables, ...

%    \usepackage[style=IEEE,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%    \addbibresource{library.bib}

    \usepackage{refstyle} % for figure references

    \usepackage{tabulary} % for easier handling of multiline entries in tables
    \usepackage{array,booktabs} % http://ctan.org/pkg/

    \usepackage{longtable} % for multi-page tables

    \usepackage{lscape} % for horizontal tables



\begin{document}
\begin{onehalfspace} % line spacing


The following table is pretty bad. One entry/row is hard to distinguish from the other. Also, it produces four warnings for underfull hboxes. Everything is aligned to the left, which is not good, but there might be a solution for this which I didn't bother to look up due to the other problems.

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{p{7.5cm}p{2cm}p{3cm}}
    \hline
    \textbf{word} & \textbf{word} & \textbf{some text} \\ \hline
    some even longer text, it \linebreak starts to get uncomfortable & some \linebreak more text & word \\
    some text that is so long that it will have \linebreak to cover multiple lines no matter what & some \linebreak text & word \\
    %\label{table:thefirstfailedattempt}
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
\bigskip


The following example is better, at least it doesn't generate warnings, decides where to include line breaks within cells and self-adjusts the width of each column. Moreover, it is easy to define the alignment for each column separately, which is something I appreciate. But the vertical centering is missing. This is not acceptable to me.

\medskip

\begin{tabulary}{14cm}{CCC} % good except for missing vertical centering
    \hline
    \textbf{word} & \textbf{word} & \textbf{some text} \\ \hline
    some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable & some more text & word \\
    some text that is so long that it will have to cover multiple lines no matter what & some text & word \\
    %\label{table:thesecondfailedattempt}
\end{tabulary}

\bigskip
\bigskip


With this solution (Table\,\ref{table:solutionfound}) I was very happy. Distinguishable rows, vertical alignment, table-label and a nice format as the cherry on top. This is what I was looking for.
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127050/vertically-align-text-in-table-in-latex

\medskip

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\caption{Data Units, Sources, and Dates}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Spread rows out...
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{7.5cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{word} & \textbf{word} & \textbf{some text} \\
    \midrule
    some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable & some more text & word \\
    some text that is so long that it will have \linebreak to cover multiple lines no matter what & some text & word \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption[The table I was happy with]{\textbf{The table I was happy with.} Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table.
    \label{table:solutionfound}}
\end{table}

\bigskip
\bigskip


But then I reached the next table (Table\,\ref{table:thetablethatistoolong}), which is quite the monster. I had to switch to landscape to fit all the columns in, but I quickly found a solution that worked. However, it is too long and stretches over multiple pages. By looking up other stackexchange answers I found out that longtable is the solution for this. But my previous solution is not compatible with longtable, which nullifies all the advances I have made in terms of linebreaks within cells, vertical centering and generally producing a respectable table.
I could split this table into three separate tables (defined by the second column), but the third table (second column is 'bar') would still be too long for one page.
\begin{landscape}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Spread rows out...
\begin{longtable}
    {>{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering}m{5cm} >{\centering}m{3cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering}m{2cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{some ID} & \textbf{a property} & \textbf{another column} & \textbf{column containing much text} & \textbf{more text} & \textbf{further specification of foo} & \textbf{further specification of bar} & \textbf{final comment} \\
    \midrule
B01  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some middle-length text  \\
B02  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B04  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B05  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B06  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B08  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text with a bit more length  \\
B10  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B11  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  word  &    &  word  \\
B12  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B13  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B15  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B16  &  foo  &  word  &  some text that is so long that it will have to cover multiple lines no matter what  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B17  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B18  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B19  &  foo  &  word  &  some text that is so long that it will have to cover multiple lines no matter what  &  word  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B21  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B23  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B25  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  some text  \\
B27  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B29  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B30  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B32  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  word  &    &  some text  \\
B34  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &    &  word  \\
B35  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B39  &  foo  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B41  &  foo  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B42  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  word  &    &  word  \\
B45  &  foo  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  some text  &    &  word  \\
B04  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &  some text  &  some text  \\
B14  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  &  word  &  some text  \\
B20  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  some text  &  some text  &  word  \\
B24  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  some text  \\
B26  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  \\
B28  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  some text  &  word  &  word  \\
B31  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  word  &  some text  &  word  \\
B33  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  word  \\
B40  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  some text  &  some text  &  word  \\
B44  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  \\
B46  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  &  word  &  word  \\
B48  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text  \\
D01  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  word  \\
D05  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  infiltrated  \\
D09  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &  infiltrated  \\
D22  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  \\
D31  &  foo+bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &  some text  \\
D02  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D03  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D04  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D06  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D07  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  word  &  some text  \\
D08  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D10  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D11  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D12  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  word  &    &  word  &  some text  \\
D13  &  bar  &  word  &  some text that is so long that it will have to cover multiple lines no matter what  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D14  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D15  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D16  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D17  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D18  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D19  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D20  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  word  &  infiltrated  \\
D21  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D23  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &    &  some text  &  some text  \\
D24  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D25  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D26  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D27  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D28  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D29  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D32  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D33  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D34  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D35  &  bar  &  word  &  some middle-length text  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D38  &  bar  &  word  &  some even longer text, it starts to get uncomfortable  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D39  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D40  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D42  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  word  &    &  word  &  word  \\
D43  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length   &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D44  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D45  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  some text  &  word  \\
D46  &  bar  &  word  &  some text with a bit more length  &  some text  &    &  word  &  word  \\
    \bottomrule
    \caption[This table is too long]{\textbf{This table is too long, you won't even see this.} Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table. Some longer text describing the table.
    \label{table:thetablethatistoolong}}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}


\end{onehalfspace} % line spacing
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I didn't take out the tabular and only changed \table to \longtable.