# forest simple vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, forest

I do not find anywhere how to specify vertical alignment for a forest obtained with the `forest` package. Here is an example of a table I'd like to have in a document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 20pt}|cc@{\hskip 20pt}cc@{\hskip 20pt}cc}
    \toprule
    Derivative & $\tau$ & $F(\tau)$ & $\tau$ & $F(\tau)$ & $\tau$ & $F(\tau)$\\ 
    \cmidrule{1-7}
    $y'$ & \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,inner sep=1pt} [] \end{forest} & $f$ & & & & \\
    \cmidrule{1-7}
    $y''$ & \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,grow=north,l=4pt,inner sep=1pt} [[]] \end{forest} & $f'f$ & & & & \\
    \cmidrule{1-7}
    $y^{(3)}$ & \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,grow=north,l=4pt,inner sep=1pt} [[][]] \end{forest} & $f''(f,f)$  & \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,grow=north,l=4pt,inner sep=1pt} [[[]]] \end{forest} & $f''(f,f)$\\
    \cmidrule{1-7}
    $y^{(4)}$ & \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,grow=north,l=4pt,inner sep=1pt} [[][][]] \end{forest} & $f^{(3)}(f,f,f)$ &
    \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,grow=north,l=4pt,inner sep=1pt} [[[]][]] \end{forest} & $f''(f,f'f)$ &
    \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,grow=north,l=4pt,inner sep=1pt} [[][[]]] \end{forest} & $f''(f'f,f)$ \\[10pt]
    & \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,grow=north,l=4pt,inner sep=1pt} [[[[]]]] \end{forest} & $f'f'f'f$ &
    \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,grow=north,l=4pt,inner sep=1pt} [[[][]]] \end{forest} & $f'f''(f, f)$ &
    \begin{forest} for tree = {circle,draw,fill,grow=north,l=4pt,inner sep=1pt} [[][[]]] \end{forest} & $f''(f'f,f)$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image]

I would like to have, for example in the second line, that the $f'f$ is aligned with the center of its corresponding tree, and not with the root.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the wrong thing. [tables - Vertical alignment in tabular cells with variable height - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height) // [vertical alignment - vertically align text in table in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127050/vertically-align-text-in-table-in-latex) (TODO figure out what the answers there are doing)

Comment: not really: the problem would be the same outside a table environment. In any case, I solved it with a adjustbox environment