# Alignment in longtable

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

I have following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable,array,lipsum,tabularx,multirow}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash} p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{b{20mm}|L{\dimexpr\textwidth-40mm\relax}@{}|R{20mm}}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
top & \lipsum[1] & bottom
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

What I get is:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

(contents of last column aligned at the bottom line)

Could someone help me to solve this?

**Final solution**
based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580377/228833) of @Zarko and on the comments of @DavidCarlisle

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum,longtable, multirow, xltabular,letltxmacro}
\RequirePackage[noprefix,refpage,intoc]{nomentbl}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\LetLtxMacro\oldnomenclature\nomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomenclature}[3][]{\oldnomenclature[#1]{#2}{#3}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\multirow[b]{\zzz}{*}{#1}}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\nomenclature{a}{\lipsum[1]}
\nomenclature{b}{\lipsum[2]}
\printnomenclature[3cm]
\end{document}
```

used together with makeindex and the makeindex-Style-File nomentbl.ist which is

```
actual '@'
quote '%'
delim_0   ""
delim_1   ""
delim_2   ""
item_0    ""
delim_t   " \\\\\n"
line_max  1000
heading_prefix   "\\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\\nomgroup{"
heading_suffix   "}} \\\\\n\\nopagebreak\\\\*[-3mm]\n\\nopagebreak{}"
headings_flag       1
group_skip        "\\\\*[-3mm]"
preamble "\n\\begin{thenomenclature}\n%
\\begin{xltabular}{\\linewidth}{@{}lL<{\\endgraf\\xdef\\zzz{\\the\\prevgraf}}@{}l@{}l@{}r@{}}\n%
\\textbf{Symbol} & \\textbf{Description} & & & \\textbf{Page} \\\\*[-4mm]\n%
\\hline \\\\*[-2mm] \n"%
postamble "\n\\end{xltabular}\n\n\\end{thenomenclature}\n"
keyword "\\nomenclatureentry"
\endinput
```

results in

[image]

Comment: so long as "bottom" is just one line always then this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303798/tabular-columns-with-different-vertical-alignment/343579#343579

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need a solution with three columns

Comment: the visual output in the referenced answer has three columns, using two columns in the markup is just an internal detail to get the alignment. Any solution is going to have to do something similar to get the alignment of the last row of the middle column.

Comment: My table here is auto-created using makeindex (it is a list for used symbols). The last columns contains the page number. Auto-formatting using the *.ist style file is possible, but I can't see an option to use this particular answer for this purpose

Comment: the underlying table primitives in tex do not support this alignment so any solution is going to require some custom code to get the effect which you will have to integrate into your auto generation somehow. Actually the easiest way (especially if you don't have vertical rules) is to put "bottom" in a row on its own, and possibly add a negative baseline space to move it up.

Comment: Is there maybe a method to "measure" the height of the content of the second column and to put the content of the third column into a box with exactly this height? Inside the box one could align the content at the bottom maybe.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166808/move-tabular-entry-to-bottom-of-row/166821#166821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- off-topic: with use of the `xltabular` instead of `longtable, you will have simpler control over column width
- using `\multirow[b]{<number of lines in adjacent cell(s)>}{*}{bottom`} you can achieve what you after, however this solution require manual tweaking: counting number of lines in the middle cell:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable, multirow, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{l|L|r}
Column 1 & Column 2     & Column 3          \\ \hline
top      & \lipsum[1]   & \multirow[b]{15}{*}{bottom}
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable, multirow, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{l|L<{\endgraf\xdef\zzz{\the\prevgraf}}|r}
Column 1 & Column 2     & Column 3          \\ \hline
top      & \lipsum[1]   & \multirow[b]{\zzz}{*}{bottom}
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\prevgraf` at the end of the middle cell would give you the line count so you'd just need to stick it in a global value to leak it to the next column

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I wasn't aware for this command. Unfortunately my effort to use it my answer wasn't fruitful. Please, be so kind and show me (us), how to use in this particular case.

Comment: I added something, feel free to use or delete as you see fit. (added to end of your answer as code in comments is horrible)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you very much!

Comment: note that assumes a single paragraph, prevgraf just gives lines on the paragraph just finished

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, this worked for me. Added my solution to my post as well.

Comment: Thank you as well @Zarko

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tested your code. It works fine. I only need to figured out, why  `<{\endgraf\xdef\zzz{\the\prevgraf}}` insert one empty line in `L` cell.  About this I will ask new question.

Comment: oh sorry that's my fault, there is a final strut added, hmm need to be a bit more carefull inserting the prevgraf no time now, sorry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, meanwhile I ask question about this. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580392/using-prevgraf-in-multirow-cells).  Please, write an answer on this.