# vertical alignment in tabularx environment

Tags: tabularx, alignment, vertical

I am using tabularx environment and in the MWE I have three columns. The first column contains short text, the second column contains long text and the third column contains short text again.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{6cm}{|p{2cm}|b{2cm}|p{2cm}|} 
short 1 & long text spanning more than one row & short 2 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

As expected, the result is that both `short 1` and `short 2` align to the bottom.

[image]

If I change the setting on middle column from `b{2cm}` to `p{cm}`, as expected both `short 1` and `short` 2 align to the top.

I would like to make `short 1` align to the top and `short 2` align to the bottom. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Following the suggestion by @NBur who pointed me out to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395356/different-vertical-alignment-of-text-in-4-column-table-tabularx), I've implemented the following changes:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}{b{2cm}<{\vfill}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{6cm}{|C|b{2cm}|p{2cm}|} 
short 1 & long text spanning more than one row & short 2 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this code brings up the text only by one line and not all the way up to the top of the cell, so it does not work.

[image]

Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different vertical alignment of text in 4-column table (tabularx)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395356/different-vertical-alignment-of-text-in-4-column-table-tabularx)

Comment: apart from the alignment you should use `tabular` not `tabularx` here as all the columns are `p` not `X`

Comment: @NBur, thank you for your reply. However, following the instruction `/vfill` brings up  the text in the cell only by one line, not all the way to the top. Do you have any other suggestion? Maybe using some kind of a box?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I need to use `tabularx` for my table, I have just stripped down all the unnecessary parts for the purpose of MWE.

Comment: It seems to me the same problem as in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580392/using-prevgraf-in-multirow-cells) and I think the same solution can be used.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to achieve with the new package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{|Q[h,2cm]|Q[m,2cm]|Q[f,2cm]|}
short 1 & long text spanning more than one row & short 2 \\
\end{tblr}

\vspace{1cm}
And if you like the second column be justified:
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tblr}{|Q[h,2cm]|Q[m,2cm,halign=j]|Q[f,2cm]|}
short 1 & long text spanning more than one row & short 2 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]