# Vertical alignment of equations including fractions in a table

Tags: tables, formatting, cell

I need to cramp a table into a tight space, but unfortunately the equations aren't aligning/fitting into it vertically. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \scriptsize
    \tabcolsep=0.05cm
    \setlength\extrarowheight{0.15cm}
    \begin{tabular}{C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.3cm}|C{4.4cm}|C{1.8cm}}
        Querschnitt & Zug/Druck & Schub & Biegung & Torsion\\\hline
        Spannung & $\sigma_w = \frac{F}{A_w}$ & $\tau_{w}= \frac{F_q}{A_w}$ & $\sigma_{wb} = \frac{M_{bx}}{W_{wbx}}$ &  $\tau_{wt} = \frac{M_t}{W_{wt}}$\\\hline
        Rechteck & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$A_w = 2a(b+t)$} & $W_{wbx} = \frac{(t+a)(b+a)^3-(t-a)(b-a)^3}{6(b+a)}$ &  $W_{wt} = 2abt$\\\cline{1-5}
        Kreis & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$A_w = \pi da$} & $W_{wb} = \frac{\pi\left[(d+a)^4 -(d-a)^4\right]}{32(d+a)}$ &  $W_{wt} = 2W_{wb}$\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And what it currently looks like:

[image]

As you can see, `\extrarowheight` fixed the issue of the equations overlapping the `\hline` on the top, but unfortunately they are still overlapping them on the bottom. In the document I'm using this table it also happens to be inconsistent for every cell, though I use the same snippet as added above.

Using `m{}` unfotunately didn't center the cells when using `\extrarowheight`, so I'm in some kind of dillema here as I can either center the equations or stop them from overlapping (on the top only). `\arraystretch` has the same effect as `\extrarowheight`.

Does anybody have a solution for this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6355/problem-with-table-vertical-alignment`?

Comment: @JPi Yep, this unfortunately breaks the equations though, even when making their cells way longer than they actually are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert "bottom [typographic] struts" to obtain more vertical whitespace between the lowest item in a formula and the horizontal line immediately below it.

Some additional suggestions:

- Provide some manual kerning for the 7 instances of `W_{w...}`.
- Since no linebreaks seem to be called for in any of the cells, you might was well use the basic `c` column type instead of a centered version of the `p` column type.
- Since the contents of almost all cells should be rendered in math mode, switching from a `tabular` environment to an `array` environment will save you from having to type lots and lots of `$` tokens.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin = 0.8cm, hmargin = 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro

\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\arraycolsep{1mm}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{1.5mm}
    $\begin{array}{@{} >{$}c<{$} |c|c|c|c @{}} % first col. in text mode
        Querschnitt & $Zug/Druck$ & $Schub$ & $Biegung$ & $Torsion$ \\ 
        \hline
        Spannung & 
          \sigma_w = \frac{F_{\vphantom{q}}}{A_{w\Bstrut}} & 
          \tau_{w}= \frac{F_{\!q}}{A_{w\Bstrut}} & 
          \sigma_{wb} = \frac{M_{bx}}{W_{\!wbx\Bstrut}} &  
          \tau_{wt} = \frac{M_t}{W_{\!wt\Bstrut}} \\ 
        \hline
        Rechteck & 
          \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A_w = 2a(b+t)} & 
          W_{\!wbx} = \frac{(t+a)(b+a)^3-(t-a)(b-a)^3}{6(b+a)\Bstrut} &  
          W_{\!wt\Bstrut} = 2abt \\ 
        \cline{1-5}
        Kreis & 
          \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A_w = \pi da} & 
          W_{\!wb} = \frac{\pi[(d+a)^{4} -(d-a)^4]}{32(d+a)} &  
          W_{\!wt} = 2W_{\!wb} \\
    \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I include your `\Bstrut` in my answer?

Comment: @Moriambar - Absolutely! Please go ahead.

Comment: Out of the proposed solutions the \Bstrut command was the most straight forward and easy to apply, so I ended up using it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I propose a "revolutionary" solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.6ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut

%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
    \scriptsize
    \tabcolsep=0.05cm
    \setlength\extrarowheight{0.15cm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}c@{\qquad}c@{\qquad}c@{\qquad}c}
    \toprule
        Querschnitt & Zug/Druck & Schub & Biegung & Torsion\\
        \midrule
        Spannung & 
        $\sigma_w = \frac{F}{A_w}$ &
        $\tau_{w}= \frac{F_q\Bstrut}{A_w}$ &
         $\sigma_{wb} = \frac{M_{bx}\Bstrut}{W_{wbx}}$ &
           $\tau_{wt} = \frac{M_t\Bstrut}{W_{wt}}$\\
        Rechteck &
         \multicolumn{2}{c}{$A_w = 2a(b+t)$} & 
         $W_{wbx} = \frac{(t+a)(b+a)^3-(t-a)(b-a)^3\Bstrut}{6(b+a)}$ &
           $W_{wt} = 2abt$\\
        Kreis &
         \multicolumn{2}{c}{$A_w = \pi da$} &
         $W_{wb} = \frac{\pi[(d+a)^4 -(d-a)^4]\Bstrut}{32(d+a)}$ &
           $W_{wt} = 2W_{wb}$\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
 \end{document}
```

Yielding:

[image]

**What I did**

1. Removed all the vertical separator. I think they are quite ugly and *in the way* of the text
2. Used some normal `c`-type columns, letting LaTeX determine the width of the specific columns
3. Inserte custom `@{\qquad}` spacing between some columns that were too much compressed (one can insert other spaces if he wants/deems them more readable)
4. Removed horizontal separators, which removed air from the equations, and replaced them with the `booktabs` rules (also: added `booktabs`)
5. Incremented the `\arraystretch` with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` as a quick way to increment vertical spacing, in order to give space to the complex equations
6. Changed your `\left[ ... \right]` to the normal ones, to have correct spacings

**EDIT**

Also, thanks to the kind @Mico

7. Defined a new `strut` to *lift* some of the numerators with subscript, a little bit above the fraction line, with a command called `\Bstrut`. I also have used it where the parentheses were a bit close to the fraction line.

Comment: Instead of inserting a few `\Bstrut` directives in the first two rows, you could also provide `\addlinespace` directives after each line break, for more whitespace between the rows.

Comment: I use `Bstrut` for space in math mode between the subscripts and the fraction line, not the hlines

Comment: Thank you for making my table fancier, but unfortunately most of the changes required more space than I have available. I ended up removing the seperators and horizontal lines after seeing how much better it looks though!

Answer (score 3):

with `cellspace` for more vertical space around cells' content and `subdepth` for better positioning of subscripts (indexes):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin = 0.8cm, hmargin = 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cellspace} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}              % subscript positioning

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} c|c|c|Sc|c @{}}
        Querschnitt     & Zug/Druck & Schub     & Biegung & Torsion         \\      \hline
        Spannung        & $\sigma_w = \frac{F}{A_{w}}$ & $\tau_{w}
                                    = \frac{F_{\!q}}{A_{w}}$ & $\sigma_{wb} 
                                    = \frac{M_{bx}}{W_{\!wbx}}$ &  $\tau_{wt} 
                                    = \frac{M_t}{W_{\!wt}}$          \\      \hline
        Rechteck        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$A_w = 2a(b+t)$} & $W_{\!wbx} 
                                                   = \frac{(t+a)(b+a)^3-(t-a)(b-a)^3}{6(b+a)}$ 
                                &  $W_{\!wt} = 2abt$                 \\      \cline{1-5}
        Kreis           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$A_w = \pi da$} 
                                & $W_{\!wb} = \frac{\pi[(d+a)^{4} -(d-a)^4]}{32(d+a)}$ 
                                    &  $W_{\!wt} = 2W_{\!wb}$               \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
An alternative with considering *Mico* comment below and use `amsmath` package for `\dfrac{...}{...}` is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin = 0.8cm, hmargin = 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cellspace} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}              % subscript positioning
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} c|c|c|Sc|c @{}}
        Querschnitt &   Zug/Druck & Schub     & Biegung & Torsion               \\      \hline
        Spannung    &   $\sigma_w = \dfrac{F}{A_{w}}$     
                        &   $\tau_{w} = \dfrac{F_{q}}{A_{w}}$    
                            &   $\sigma_{wb} = \dfrac{M_{bx}}{W_{wbx}}$
                                &   $\tau_{wt} = \dfrac{M_t}{W_{wt}}$          \\      \hline
        Rechteck   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$A_w = 2a(b+t)$}  
                            &   $W_{wbx} = \dfrac{(t+a)(b+a)^3-(t-a)(b-a)^3}{6(b+a)}$ 
                                &   $W_{wt} = 2abt$                           \\      \cline{1-5}
        Kreis      &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$A_w = \pi da$} 
                                &   $W_{wb} = \dfrac{\pi\left[(d+a)^{4} -(d-a)^4\right]}{32(d+a)}$ 
                                    &  $W_{wt} = 2W_{wb}$                   \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty neat solution, unfortunately the code isn't working in my current document though (No issues in a fresh one). So while I'm not able to use it here, I'm surely going to apply this technique to future one!

Comment: @Skydiver, the code is very standard. If you have in preamble of your document loaded in my MWE used packages (in comparison to your MWE is new only `subdepth`), the solution should work. Since your real preamble is not known, I can't see what could be cause of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This fits the normal text width for `article`; using `\mfrac` from `nccmath` the fractions are not so unbearably small.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\footnotesize

\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
Querschnitt & Zug/Druck & Schub & Biegung & Torsion\\
\midrule
Spannung &
 $\sigma_w = \mfrac{F}{A_w}$ &
 $\tau_{w}= \mfrac{F_q}{A_w}$ &
 $\sigma_{wb} = \mfrac{M_{bx}}{W_{wbx}}$ &
 $\tau_{wt} = \mfrac{M_t}{W_{wt}}$ \\
\addlinespace
Rechteck &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{$A_w = 2a(b+t)$} &
  $W_{wbx} = \mfrac{(t+a)(b+a)^3-(t-a)(b-a)^3}{6(b+a)}$ &
  $W_{wt} = 2abt$\\
\addlinespace
Kreis &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{$A_w = \pi da$} &
  $W_{wb} = \mfrac{\pi\left[(d+a)^4 -(d-a)^4\right]}{32(d+a)}$ &
  $W_{wt} = 2W_{wb}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]